# How to print a signed integer as hexadecimal number in two's complement with python?

Tags: python, integer, hex, signed, twos-complement

I have a negative integer (4 bytes) of which I would like to have the hexadecimal form of its two's complement representation.

```
>>> i = int("-312367")
>>> "{0}".format(i)
'-312367'
>>> "{0:x}".format(i)
'-4c42f'
```

But I would like to see "FF..."

Comment: 'hexadecimal form of its two's complement representation' ? How is that in the least bit helpful?

Comment: See if this answer to a related question is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python/1605553#1605553

Comment: Konrad, perhaps he's preparing a tool to show his students how it's done. Or he's curious. Or he's got an API to follow. Or a buddy bet him a case of beer that Perl could do it better.

Comment: Yes, bitstrings hex property seems to return what I need as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Konrad,1: No, why?
@Konrad,2: Sorry if it's not clear to you what I mean -- how would you put it?

Comment: @Konrad, if he's in a management class, then he's doing everything correctly (by delegating)  :-)

Comment: @Konrad It's sometimes useful for debugging binary files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way (for 16 bit numbers):

```
>>> x=-123
>>> hex(((abs(x) ^ 0xffff) + 1) & 0xffff)
'0xff85'
```

(Might not be the most elegant way, though)

Comment: This doesn't work for positive numbers. If x=1 you get `0xffff` (-1 in 16-bit two's complement), instead of `0x0001`.

Comment: The example given was a negative integer, but the question was "How to print a signed integer... in two's complement [representation]". It could be confusing if this answer only works for negative signed integers.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module:

```
>>> bitstring.BitArray('int:32=-312367').hex
'0xfffb3bd1'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> x = -123
>>> bits = 16
>>> hex((1 << bits) + x)
'0xff85'
>>> bits = 32
>>> hex((1 << bits) + x)
'0xffffff85'
```

Comment: For 123, isn't the 16-bit 2's complement representation 0x007b? 0xff85 would be for -123.

Comment: @dcoles, no the sum of 123 and it's 2's complement should be 0 (the carry/overflow bit is discarded) It doesn't matter whether you want to treat `0xff85` as signed or unsigned.

Comment: I agree that the 2's complement (the operation on binary numbers) of 0x007b is 0xff85, but I believe the question was about the 2's complement signed number representation.

Comment: @dcoles, ah. I think I get what you are saying. It's proably clearer if I make `x = -123`

Answer (score 3):

Simple

```
>>> hex((-4) & 0xFF)
'0xfc'
```

Answer (score 2):

To treat an integer as a binary value, you bitwise-and it with a mask of the desired bit-length.

For example, for a 4-byte value (32-bit) we mask with `0xffffffff`:

```
>>> format(-1 & 0xffffffff, "08X")
'FFFFFFFF'
>>> format(1 & 0xffffffff, "08X")
'00000001'
>>> format(123 & 0xffffffff, "08X")
'0000007B'
>>> format(-312367 & 0xffffffff, "08X")
'FFFB3BD1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html) module performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python bytes objects. The packed bytes object offers access to individual byte values.
This can be used to display the underlying (C) integer representation.

```
>>> packed = struct.pack('>i',i) # big-endian integer
>>> type(packed)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> packed
b'\xff\xfb;\xd1'
>>> "%X%X%X%X" % tuple(packed)
'FFFB3BD1'
>>>
```