# How can I use 64 bit unsigned integers as entity keys in App Engine's datastore and retain sort order?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have unsigned 64 bit integers that I would like to use as App Engine datastore keys. Unfortunately the NDB datastore API only seems to allow [signed 64 bit integers](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/key.py#85) with a max size of `pow(2, 63)`.

I could two's complement the integers but I rely on the sort order in the datastore for queries so I want `0xffffffffffffffff` coming after `0x0` in ascending sort order not before it . I believe this would happen if I two's complement my 64 bit unsigned integers as `0xffffffffffffffff` would be interpreted as `-1` by the datastore index and `0x0` would be interpreted as `0` for example.

I could change each unsigned 64 bit key from an integer to a string or even a hex string but that would take up a lot more space in the datastore than keeping the keys as 64 bit integers.

Comment: Use them as strings, thats your only choice.

Comment: Agreed. And don't worry about the storage cost of the string vs. the integer.  You could probably use a fixed-width base-64 encoding that preserves the sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just encode your unsigned values as signed values with a simple constant offset of `pow(2, 63)`.

This "shifts" all values "downwards" without messing up sort order, from the [0, 2^64) range representable by an unsigned 64-bit integer into the range [-2^63, 2^63) representable by a (typical implementation of a) signed 64-bit integer.

```py
def encode(unsigned_64_bit_int):
    return unsigned_64_bit_int - pow(2, 63)

def decode(signed_64_bit_int):
    return signed_64_bit_int + pow(2, 63)
```

(You can also replace `pow(2, 63)` with the equivalent constant `0x8000000000000000`, if you find it clearer or effecting performance in a way that matters.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Tim Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201324/tim-hoffman) and [Guido van Rossum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum) the answer is you **cannot** use 64 bit unsigned integers as entity keys in App Engine's datastore and retain sort order.

If you don't care about sort order then you could [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python) the unsigned 64 bit integer and use that.

In the end I changed my unsigned 64 bit integer into a fixed width hex string and saved that as the key as it seemed to be most convenient at the expense of some space.

The functions I use look like this:

```
def to_hex_string(unsigned_64bit_int):
    return '{:016x}'.format(my_unsigned_64bit_int)

def to_unsigned_64bit_int(hex_string):
    return int(hex_string, 16)
```

If space is critical [Guido van Rossum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum) suggested using a base-64 encoding that preserves sort order. I am not sure if the Python [base64 module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) encoders preserve sort order.

Comment: Unless I'm terribly misunderstanding something this is wrong. You can trivially shift all values in the range [0, 2^64) into the range [-2^63, 2^63) without messing up sort order by just substracting 2^63 from each value. This converts from unsigned to signed without messing up the sort order.