# Removing duplicates from Pandas rows, replace them with NaNs, shift NaNs to end of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Problem

How to remove duplicate cells from each row, considering each row separately (and perhaps replace them with NaNs) in a Pandas dataframe?

It would be even better if we could shift all newly created NaNs to the end of each row.

---

### Related but different posts

Posts on **how to remove entire rows** which are deemed duplicate:

- [how do I remove rows with duplicate values of columns in pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885093/how-do-i-remove-rows-with-duplicate-values-of-columns-in-pandas-data-frame)
- [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)
- [Remove duplicate rows from Pandas dataframe where only some columns have the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481768/remove-duplicate-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-where-only-some-columns-have-the-sam)

Post on **how to remove duplicates from a list which is in a Pandas column**:

- [Remove duplicates from rows and columns (cell) in a dataframe, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088686/remove-duplicates-from-rows-and-columns-cell-in-a-dataframe-python)

Answer given here returns a series of strings, not a dataframe.

---

## Reproducible setup

```
import pandas as pd
```

Let's create a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
                   'b': ['B', 'D', 'B', 'B'],
                   'c': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
                   'd': ['D', 'D', 'B', 'A']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

`df` created:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    | a   | b   | c   | d   |
|----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|  0 | A   | B   | C   | D   |
|  1 | A   | D   | C   | D   |
|  2 | C   | B   | C   | B   |
|  3 | B   | B   | A   | A   |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

<sub>(Printed using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885295/8565438).)</sub>

---

## A solution

One way of dropping duplicates from each row, considering each row separately:

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row).drop_duplicates(keep='first'),axis='columns')
```

using [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful/890188) function, [pd.Series()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), & [Series.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html).

Shove all NaNs to the end of each row, using [Shift NaNs to the end of their respective rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970751/shift-nans-to-the-end-of-their-respective-rows):

```
df.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x[x.notnull()].values.tolist()+x[x.isnull()].values.tolist()),axis='columns')
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    | 0   | 1   | 2   | 3   |
|----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|  0 | A   | B   | C   | D   |
|  1 | A   | D   | C   | nan |
|  2 | C   | B   | nan | nan |
|  3 | B   | A   | nan | nan |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Just as we wished.

---

## Question

Is there a **more efficient way** to do this? Perhaps with some built-in Pandas functions?

Comment: I tried to find a question which this post is a duplicate of, but to my surprise, I haven't found any which is a good fit for a dupe. I welcome any suggestions regarding duplicates.

Comment: You never defined what you mean by *'duplicates'*, especially since you're using a different meaning to normal ('distinct values across multiple columns, considered row-wise'), and your title is overly broad, people will wrongly be sent here by Google and SO search. Wrt your example, on row 1 why did you not remove the second 'C' from column 'c', but you did remove the second 'D' from column 'd'? This makes no sense. Also, "replace cells with NaNs" is not really "remove", so this is two-questions-in-one and the code solutions will be different (`fillna`, `duplicated`, `drop_duplicates`, etc.).

Comment: In your use-case, you have **multiple columns all considered equivalent**, same dtype, don't-care about the names. So 'FirstName=Murphy, LastName=Brown' would be considered a 'duplicate' of 'Brown, Murphy'; or a zipcode of 77024 and income of 60001 or customer-id of 45678 would all be considered 'equivalent' to other permutations of the same values, across columns. This is absolutely not a standard definition of 'duplicates'. Your data is really just an array, not a genuine dataframe, and the part *"shift all newly-created NaNs to the end of each row"* proves it.

Comment: I don't get the the concern: "on row 1 why did you not remove the second 'C' from column 'c', but you did remove the second 'D' from column 'd'?" There is only one 'C' in row 1.

Comment: About the others: I hope your edit addresses these concerns & the post is now ok.

Comment: Although the beginning of the new question title, ie: "Removing Pandas rows with duplicate values across multiple columns" is misleading I think, since we are not actually removing the rows.

Comment: Could you find a question title to address this?

Comment: Then your example is meant to illustrate your (non-standard) definition of 'duplicate': "duplicate value within same row" (not within column):  so on row 1 the 'D's are considered duplicates, but the 'C' in column 'c' is **not** (although it would be a duplicate if we scanned column 'c' vertically). And also, you don't want to remove rows; only replace duplicate values with NAs. (That's not standard use-case). Anyway I edited the title once more to state this.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware usually duplicate is meant within columns. I like the new question title, thanks.

Comment: You know, if you only have a reasonably small well-defined set of distinct values across columns (do you?), I wouldn't start by using a dataframe column for each value, just a Python set, or [bit-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845686/python-bit-array-performant). Especially if the original order didn't matter. Can you give us a little context? Are these zipcodes? people's names? word-vectors? search index tags? something else?

Comment: I don't remember the exact context, but these were indeed names (ie strings)... How I ended up having this exact situation, I can't recall now, but I'll comment later if I manage to remember.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can `stack` and then `drop_duplicates` that way.  Then we need to pivot with the help of a `cumcount` level. The `stack` preserves the order the values appear in along the rows and the `cumcount` ensures that the `NaN` will appear in the end.

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index().drop(columns='level_1').drop_duplicates()

df1['col'] = df1.groupby('level_0').cumcount()
df1 = (df1.pivot(index='level_0', columns='col', values=0)
          .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

   0  1    2    3
0  A  B    C    D
1  A  D    C  NaN
2  C  B  NaN  NaN
3  B  A  NaN  NaN
```

---

#### Timings

Assuming 4 columns, let's see how a bunch of these methods compare as the number of rows grow. The `map` and `apply` solutions have a good advantage when things are small, but they become a bit slower than the more involved `stack` + `drop_duplicates` + `pivot` solution as the DataFrame gets longer. Regardless, they all start to take a while for a large DataFrame.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def stack(df):
    df1 = df.stack().reset_index().drop(columns='level_1').drop_duplicates()

    df1['col'] = df1.groupby('level_0').cumcount()
    df1 = (df1.pivot(index='level_0', columns='col', values=0)
              .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
    return df1

def apply_drop_dup(df):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().tolist(),
                                           axis=1).to_dict(), orient='index')

def apply_unique(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(df.apply(pd.Series.unique, axis=1).tolist())


def list_map(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(list(map(pd.unique, df.values)))


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), (n, 4)),
                                 columns=list('abcd')), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: stack(df),
        lambda df: apply_drop_dup(df),
        lambda df: apply_unique(df),
        lambda df: list_map(df),
    ],
    labels=['stack', 'apply_drop_dup', 'apply_unique', 'list_map'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(18)],
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x.compare(y).empty,  
    xlabel='~len(df)'
)
```

[image]

---

Finally, if preserving the order in which the values originally appeared within each row is unimportant, you can use `numpy`. To de-duplicate you sort then check for differences. Then create an output array that shifts values to the right. Because this method will always return 4 columns, we require a `dropna` to match the other output in the case that every row has fewer than 4 unique values.

```
def with_numpy(df):
    arr = np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)
    r = np.roll(arr, 1, axis=1)
    r[:, 0] = np.NaN
    
    arr = np.where((arr != r), arr, np.NaN)
    
    # Move all NaN to the right. Credit @Divakar
    mask = pd.notnull(arr)
    justified_mask = np.flip(np.sort(mask, axis=1), 1)
    out = np.full(arr.shape, np.NaN, dtype=object) 
    out[justified_mask] = arr[mask]
    
    return pd.DataFrame(out, index=df.index).dropna(how='all', axis='columns')

with_numpy(df)
#   0  1    2    3
#0  A  B    C    D
#1  A  C    D  NaN
#2  B  C  NaN  NaN     # B/c this method sorts, B before C
#3  A  B  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), (n, 4)),
                                 columns=list('abcd')), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: stack(df),
        lambda df: with_numpy(df),
    ],
    labels=['stack', 'with_numpy'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(3, 22)],
    # Lazy check to deal with string/NaN and irrespective of sort order. 
    equality_check=lambda x, y: (np.sort(x.fillna('ZZ').to_numpy(), 1) 
                                 == np.sort(y.fillna('ZZ').to_numpy(), 1)).all(),
    xlabel='len(df)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This indeed works. Going to leave the question open a bit in case someone comes up with a simpler solution, if that doesn't happen, will definitely accept this one.

Comment: @ALollz: thanks for the `perfplot`. I am truly curious about the performance of each solution, but I am suck at setting it. I already upvoted yours. Otherwise, I would upvote it again on the `perfplot` :)

Answer (score 14):

try something new

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(pd.unique, df.values)))
Out[447]: 
   0  1     2     3
0  A  B     C     D
1  A  D     C  None
2  C  B  None  None
3  B  A  None  None
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `apply` and construct a new dataframe by `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` with option `orient='index'`

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().tolist(),
                                               axis=1).to_dict(), orient='index')

Out[268]:
   0  1     2     3
0  A  B     C     D
1  A  D     C  None
2  C  B  None  None
3  B  A  None  None
```

Note: `None` practically is similar to `NaN`. If you want exact `NaN`. Just chain additional `.fillna(np.nan)`

Answer (score 4):

You could search for duplicates on the `row` axis and then sort out the results to "push" the `Nan` at the end of the rows by sorting them out with a specific key:

```
duplicates = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1)
df.where(~duplicates, np.nan).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x, key=pd.isnull)), axis=1)
```

Output

```
| 0   | 1   | 2   | 3   |
|:----|:----|:----|:----|
| A   | B   | C   | D   |
| A   | D   | C   | NaN |
| C   | B   | NaN | NaN |
| B   | A   | NaN | NaN |
```

Answer (score 4):

Apply `pd.Series.unique` on each row, extract the result and re-contruct the dataframe:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.apply(pd.Series.unique, axis=1).tolist()))

   0  1     2     3
0  A  B     C     D
1  A  D     C  None
2  C  B  None  None
3  B  A  None  None
```