# convert dataframe row of repeated strings to a non repeated list

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to convert a large dataframe row of repeated strings to  a non repeated list via `dict.fromkeys()`. I have a simple df here for demonstration.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['X'],'B':['X'],'C':['X'],'D':['Y'],'E':['Y'],'F':['Y']})
df_list = df.values.tolist()
l= list(dict.fromkeys(df_list))
```

Output: `df,df_list,error`

```
     A  B  C  D  E  F
  0  X  X  X  Y  Y  Y

[['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']]

           l= list(dict.fromkeys(df_list))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Desired Output:

list of x,y

I recognise that the problem is due to a list within a list....perhaps there is a direct way of extracting non repeated elements from the dataframe row?

Comment: What should be the out put here? `X,Y` ?

Comment: correct, updated post.

Comment: won't `df_list[0]`  give you the list?

Comment: What do you want as final output? a list like `lst = ['X','Y']` ?

Comment: `np.unique(df.to_numpy())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.iloc[0,:].unique().tolist()
```

Edit:
A more Python driven methodology could be used:

```
list(set(df.iloc[0,:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `dict.fromkeys()`, can do:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(df_list[0]).keys())
```

But I would suggest other methods, such as:

```
df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row).drop_duplicates(keep='first'),axis='columns').loc[0,:].to_list()
```

or:

```
 df.stack().reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')[0].drop_duplicates().to_list()
```

or:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(pd.Series.unique, axis=0)).loc[0,:].drop_duplicates().to_list()
```

or:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(map(pd.unique, df.values))).loc[0,:].to_list()
```

These are based on: [Removing duplicates from Pandas rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583502/removing-duplicates-from-pandas-rows).

Comment: I dont insist on it but good to know your proposal also works.  thanks.

Comment: @user9106985, alright; added some other methods in case you need them.

Comment: Nice alternatives! Thanks