# Two's complement sign extension python?

Tags: python, twos-complement

I'm wondering if there's a way to do a two's complement sign extension as you would in C/C++ in Python, using standard libraries (preferably on a bitarray).

C/C++:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int x = 0xFF;
    x <<= (32 - 8);
    x >>= (32 - 8);
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

And here's a Python function I've written which (in my testing) accomplishes the same thing. I'm simply wondering if there's a built-in (or just faster) way of doing it:

```
def sign_extend(value, bits):
    highest_bit_mask = 1 << (bits - 1)
    remainder = 0
    for i in xrange(bits - 1):
        remainder = (remainder << 1) + 1

    if value & highest_bit_mask == highest_bit_mask:
        value = (value & remainder) - highest_bit_mask
    else:
        value = value & remainder
    return value
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1604464/2823755

Comment: Ah, didn't see that earlier for some reason.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It is for a string conversion though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code delivers the same results as your function, but is a bit shorter.  Also, obviously, if you are going to apply this to a lot of data, you can pre-calculate both the masks.

```
def sign_extend(value, bits):
    sign_bit = 1 << (bits - 1)
    return (value & (sign_bit - 1)) - (value & sign_bit)
```

Comment: very clever indeed

Comment: Is their a small example on how to use it ? sign_extend(0xFF, 32) produces 255 which is same as 0xFF. I expect it to be 0xFFFFFFFF instead

Comment: sign_extend(10,4) produces -6 which is signed equivalent (2's complement) value of unsigned value 10 when represented with 4 bits. sign_extend(10,5) produces value 10 or '0b1010'. I expected it would produce '0b11010' instead or value 26. This doesn't appear sign extension operation to me but rather signed representation of a value in given number of bits

Comment: The purpose of this function is to extend the sign bit of a fixed width integer into a Python int, not to do negation.  The apparent negation you are seeing with sign_extend(10, 4) is because 10 cannot actually be represented in a 4 bit two's-complement value.  But 10 can be represented in a 5 bit two's complement value, and it's sign bit is -- wait for it -- zero.  Which is extended properly by the function.  Now if you put in 26, 5, then, yeah, you'll see a negative number come out.

Comment: @nurabha You should call it this way: sign_extend(0xFF, 8).  The bits argument is the number of bits in the input; the output is always the size of a Python signed integer.