# How to sign extend a signed number represented in 2's complement format in Python?

Tags: python

```
#n = input signed number (2's complement)
#b = number of bits used for representing input singed number
#k = number of bit by which number n is to be sign extended

def signExtend(n,b,k):
    # Function should return signed number of bit length (b+k) with k most significant bits as sign bits
```

For example, if b=4, k=3, n = 10 (2's complement representation 4'b1010), then the function should return 122 (2's complement representation 7'b1111010). However if n = 5 (4'b0101), then the function should return 5 (7'b0000101).

I have seen some posts (such as [Two's complement sign extension python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030412/twos-complement-sign-extension-python) ) which seem to do sign extension, but the result they produce is very different than what I expect to produce above. How to achieve above in Python ?

Comment: Sounds like you just want something like `mask = (1 << (b + k)) - 1; return n & mask`. Does that work?

Comment: Why is 4'b1010 supposed to be negative but 7'b1111010 is supposed to be positive?