# Rotate bits in python

Tags: python, hash, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Out of curiosity, I was seeing what the operations to transform an object's id into its hash look like in the string domain, rather than using the usual bitwise operations like `^`, `|`, `&`, `~`.

```
class A:
    pass

def my_hash(a):
    bits = format(id(a), '064b')
    rot4 = bits[-4:] + bits[:-4]
    n = int(rot4, 2)
    return n

for _ in xrange(10):
    a = A()
    print hash(a) == my_hash(a), hash(a), my_hash(a)
```

But as you can see below, the function below isn't correct some of the time.  What am I missing?

```
>>> run /tmp/thing.py
True 272331835 272331835
False -9223372036582443978 9223372037127107638
True 272331835 272331835
False -9223372036582443978 9223372037127107638
True 272331835 272331835
False -9223372036582443978 9223372037127107638
True 272331835 272331835
False -9223372036582443978 9223372037127107638
True 272331835 272331835
False -9223372036582443978 9223372037127107638
```

Comment: And the numbers flip-flop because each iteration Python gets to reuse the just-freed memory slot; `A()` is first assigned to memory position *foo* and bound to `a`, then the next iteration a new `A()` is assigned memory position *bar*, rebinding that to `a`, at which point the older instance at *foo* is freed (reference count dropped to 0 since `a` no longer references it).  So the next iteration `A()` is stored in location *foo*, and *bar* is freed, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash produces a *signed* integer, your code produces an unsigned integer.

For your first incorrect result, the `id(a)` value was `4357309288`; that's `0000000000000000000000000000000100000011101101110100001101101000` in 64 bits. The last 4 bits are `1000`, moving those to the start gives the binary value of `1000000000000000000000000000000000010000001110110111010000110110`, which is `--9223372036582443978` when interpreted as a [2's complement signed integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), because that first bit, the sign bit, is set to `1`.

`int(rot4, 2)` on the other hand, always interprets the input as an *unsigned*, unlimited length integer, so you get `9223372037127107638` instead.

Python doesn't have any 'easy' options to interpret a string containing a binary number to a signed integer, you could use the `bitstring` library for ease:

```
>>> from bitstring import Bits
>>> bits = Bits(int=4357309288, length=64)
>>> bits[-4:]
Bits('0x8')
>>> bits[-4:] + bits[:-4]
Bits('0x80000000103b7436')
>>> (bits[-4:] + bits[:-4]).int
-9223372036582443978L
>>> (bits[-4:] + bits[:-4]).uint
9223372037127107638L
```

The `.int` and `.uint` give you a signed and unsigned integer interpretation, respectively.

Using `bitstring` I get the correct output:

```
>>> def my_hash(a):
...     bits = Bits(int=id(a), length=64)
...     return (bits[-4:] + bits[:-4]).int
...
>>> for _ in xrange(10):
...     a = A()
...     print hash(a) == my_hash(a), hash(a), my_hash(a)
...
True -9223372036585854145 -9223372036585854145
True 268921659 268921659
True -9223372036585854145 -9223372036585854145
True 268921659 268921659
True -9223372036585854145 -9223372036585854145
True 268921659 268921659
True -9223372036585854145 -9223372036585854145
True 268921659 268921659
True -9223372036585854145 -9223372036585854145
True 268921659 268921659
```

If you want to stick to the standard library, use [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python) to grab yourself a `twos_comp()` function:

```
>>> twos_comp(9223372037127107638, 64)
-9223372036582443978L
```

Your function then would be:

```
def my_hash(a):
    bits = format(id(a), '064b')
    rot4 = bits[-4:] + bits[:-4]
    n = twos_comp(int(rot4, 2), 64)
    return n
```