# Two Complement's Python (with as least bits as possible)

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I am trying to output the binary representation of an negative number with the least bytes available each time.

Example:

```
-3 -> 101
-10 -> 10110
```

Comment: Can you show said try?

Comment: And your question is? Write this code for me? Give me a library that does this? Both of these are off topic, sorry. Show your research and what you tried to solve the task.

Comment: How is `-3` `101`? `bin(-3) == '-0b11'`

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/q/1604464/2800918

Comment: @CAB Good find, but there are better ways to do this in Python 3.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What do you want to output if the input is positive? Do you want 5 to return '0101'? I assume so, otherwise you won't be able to distinguish positive numbers from negative ones.

Comment: @LutzHorn [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using the `.bit_length` method of Python 3 integers. It also uses the string `.format` method to do the integer to binary string conversion. This function returns a string starting with '0' for non-negative numbers so that they can be distinguished from negative numbers.

```
def twos_complement(n):
    m = n + 1 if n < 0 else n
    bitlen = 1 + m.bit_length()
    mask = (1 << bitlen) - 1
    return '{0:0{1}b}'.format(n & mask, bitlen)

for i in (-10, -3, 0, 3, 10):
    print('{:3}: {}'.format(i, twos_complement(i)))

print('- ' * 30)

for i in range(-15, 16):
    print(i, twos_complement(i))
```

**output**

```
-10: 10110
 -3: 101
  0: 0
  3: 011
 10: 01010
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
-15 10001
-14 10010
-13 10011
-12 10100
-11 10101
-10 10110
-9 10111
-8 1000
-7 1001
-6 1010
-5 1011
-4 100
-3 101
-2 10
-1 1
0 0
1 01
2 010
3 011
4 0100
5 0101
6 0110
7 0111
8 01000
9 01001
10 01010
11 01011
12 01100
13 01101
14 01110
15 01111
```

---

#### How it works

Python uses a modified form of two's complement to represent integers. Python integers have no size limit, so negative integers behave as if they have an *infinite* number of leading 1 bits, as explained in the [Python Wiki article on Bitwise Operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

The `int.bit_length` method tells us the minimum number of bits required to represent a number, we want one more bit than that so that all our non-negative numbers will start with 0 and all the negative numbers start with a 1. We need to modify that slightly to ensure that numbers of the form `-2**n` will only get a single leading one bit, we do that by adding 1 to all the negative numbers when calculating the bit length.

To select the bits we want we need a bit mask of the appropriate length. If the bit length is 4, we want a mask of 1111 = `2**4 - 1`; we _could calculate it by using exponentiation, but it's more efficient to use bit shifting: `(1 << bitlen) - 1`. We then do the bitwise AND operation `n & mask` to select the bits we want. Fortunately, Python gives us a non-negative number when we perform such masking operations. :)

Finally we convert the resulting integer to a string using the `.format` method. We use a nested format specification so we can dynamically specify the correct length of the output string. In

```
'{0:0{1}b}'.format(n & mask, bitlen)
```

the first 0 of the format spec says that we're converting the value of the 0 arg in the argument list (`n & mask`), the `:0{1}b` says to convert it to binary, padded with leading zeroes if necessary, using the value of the 1 arg in the argument list (`bitlen`) as the total string length.

You can read about nested format specs in the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) section of the docs:

> A *format_spec* field can also include nested replacement fields
>   within it. These nested replacement fields may contain a field name,
>   conversion flag and format specification, but deeper nesting is not
>   allowed. The replacement fields within the *format_spec* are
>   substituted before the *format_spec* string is interpreted. This
>   allows the formatting of a value to be dynamically specified.

Comment: can you explain me a little bit the logic of the code?
thanks it seems to work

Comment: should -8 just be 1000?

Comment: @ΣΤΑΥΡΟΣΑΒΡΑΜΙΔΗΣ Sorry about the delay, but hopefully what I've written makes sense. :)