# Replicating this Java hash in Python

Tags: java, python, hash, byte

I'm trying to replicate this hashing code in Python, but both languages handles bytes differently and generating very different outputs.

Can someone guide me here ?

**Java Code (Original Code)**

```java
public static String hash(String filePath, String salt) {

        String finalHash = null;
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            byte[] dataDigest = md.digest(data);
            byte[] hashDigest = md.digest(salt.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            byte[] xorBytes = new byte[dataDigest.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataDigest.length && i < hashDigest.length; i++) {
                xorBytes[i] = (byte) (dataDigest[i] << 1 ^ hashDigest[i] >> 1);
            }

            finalHash = (new HexBinaryAdapter()).marshal(xorBytes);
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalHash;
    }
```

**Python Code (Translated by me)**

```py
def generate_hash(file_path: str, salt: bytes) -> str:
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    hashed_file = sha1(data).digest()
    hashed_salt = sha1(salt).digest()

    xor_bytes = []

    for i in range(len(hashed_file)):
        xor_bytes.append((hashed_file[i] << 1 ^ hashed_salt[i] >> 1))

    return ''.join(map(chr, xor_bytes))  # This is probably not equivalent of HexBinaryAdapter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- The shift operations are wrongly implemented in the Python code:

  In the Python code the generated hash is stored in a bytes-like object as a list of *unsigned* integer values between `0` and `255` [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest), e.g. `0xc8 = 11001000 = 200`. In Java, integers are stored as *signed* values, whereby the two's complement is used to represent negative numbers [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)[[3]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). The value `0x8c` would be interpreted as `-56` if stored in a `byte` variable.

  The `>>`-operator produces a different result on the *binary* level for signed and unsigned values, because it is an *arithmetic* shift operator which preserves the sign [[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)[[5]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)[[6]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). Example:

  ```
  signed       -56 >> 1 = 1110 0100 = -28
  unsigned     200 >> 1 = 0110 0100 = 100
  ```

  The `<<`-operator, on the other hand, does not cause the above problem, but can lead to values that cannot be represented by a byte. Example:

  ```
  signed       -56 << 1 = 1 1001 0000 = -112
  unsigned     200 << 1 = 1 1001 0000 = 400
  ```

  For these reasons, in the Python code the following line

  ```
  xor_bytes.append((hashed_file[i] << 1 ^ hashed_salt[i] >> 1))
  ```

  has to be replaced by

  ```
  xor_bytes.append((hashed_file[i] << 1 ^ tc(hashed_salt[i]) >> 1) & 0xFF)
  ```

  where

  ```
  def tc(val):
      if val > 127:
          val = val - 256
      return val
  ```

  determines the negative value of the two's complement representation (or more sophisticated with *bitwise* operators see [[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9147327)).

  The use of the *bitwise and* (`&`) with `0xFF` ensures that only the relevant byte is taken into account in the Python code, analogous to the Java code [[5]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

- There are several ways to convert the list/bytes-like object into a hexadecimal string (as in the Java code), e.g. with [[8]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes)[[9]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex)

  ```
  bytes(xor_bytes).hex()
  ```

  or with [[8]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes)[[10]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) (as binary string)

  ```
  binascii.b2a_hex(bytes(xor_bytes))
  ```

- In the Python code the encoding of the salt must be taken into account. Since the salt is already passed as a *binary* string (in the Java code it is passed as a string), the encoding must be performed before the function is called:

  ```
  saltStr = 'MySalt'
  salt = saltStr.encode('ISO-8859-1')
  ```

  For a functional consistency with the Java code, the salt would have to be passed as a string and the encoding would have to be performed within the function.

Comment: I was comparing the data right now and noticed the issue with bytes in java vs python. With the corrections supplied now the code returns the same output. Thank you very much !!