# Convert negative integer to two's complement supporting hex in python

Tags: python, hex, twos-complement

I'm trying to reverse engineer a twos complement GPS code, where the GPS code is a representation of a two's complement number in hex.

For example, 0xFEA1C83D is -22951875 in decimal.

Using Python, how can I convert -22951875 into 0xFEA1C83D?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python?

Comment: I have, but none of those solutions are working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `int.to_bytes` and `binarray.hexlify`:

```
import binascii
binascii.hexlify((-22951875).to_bytes(4, byteorder="big", signed=True))
# b'fea1c83d'
```

Comment: Clear and concise! Thank you, iz_