# how to convert decimal to two's complement with python?this is my program code, is there any other way to code it?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner here. I'm trying to specify convert decimal to two's complement . Is there a way that I can shorten this code without using this code?

here's my code

```py
inputNum = random.randint(2,100)
angkaku = bin(inputNum)
string_angkaku = '{0:b}'.format(int(inputNum))
number = int(string_angkaku,2)
two_comp = (1)*(255 + 1 - number)
slicing_tc = bin(two_comp)[2:]
```

Comment: Hey there! StackOverflow is a site for coding related problems / challenges. If you want your code to be reviewed or improved, you may want use a different stackexchange website - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeahh i mean is there any codes to solve my problrm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two's Complement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python)