# Python: How to change hex string int integer?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Hello, I want to use some string like "0xFF123456" as a 32-bit unsigned integer.
Please give me some advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python

Answer (score 5):

`a = int("0xFF123456", 0)`

If it doesn't have a `0x` prefix you could also use:

`a = int("FF123456", 16)`

Comment: Thank you!
Using zero is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> int('0xFF123456', 16)
4279383126
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>>>print int("0xFF123456",0)
```

or

```
>>>print int("0xFF123456",16)
```

Comment: Thank you!
Using zero option is what I want.