# Python - Converting Hex to INT/CHAR

Tags: python, hex, decode

I am having some difficulty changing a hex to an int/char (char preferably). Via the website;
http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ I enter the hex of C0A80026 into the hex box, in the DEC / CHAR box it correctly outputs the IP I expected it to contain.

This data is being pulled from an external database and I am not aware how it is being saved so all I have to work with is the hex string itself.

I have tried using the `binascii.unhexlify` function to see if I could decode it but I fear that I may not have a great enough understanding of hex to appreciate what I am doing.

Attemping to print just using an int() cast also has not produced the required results. I need some way to convert from that hex string (or one similar) to the original IP.

UPDATE: For anyone who comes across this in the future I modified the below answer slightly to provide an exact printout as an IP by using;

```
dec_output = str(int(hex_input[0:2], 16)) + "." +  str(int(hex_input[2:4], 16)) + "." + str(int(hex_input[4:6], 16)) + "." + str(int(hex_input[6:8], 16))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: That solution doesn't work with my problem

Comment: Please explain exactly how the duplication question is not a duplicate.  Details matter.  "doesn't work with my problem" is too vague to mean anything.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had compared them already. My problem is related to decoding hex into an IP address which the other question does not cover. Also although I do not know a great deal about hex or python there are no related questions which suggests that our similarity ends at trying to decode hex but both trying to reach two different ends

Comment: It helps to avoid all assumptions.  I still don't understand why the supplied question is not the answer to your question because (1) I don't understand the nuances of your question and (2) I don't understand the gaps in your knowledge.  Rather than assume, please **update** your question to detail -- specifically -- why a widely-accepted existing answer isn't appropriate for this.  Details matter.  And **updates** to the question are better than comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get 4 separate numbers from this, then treat it as 4 separate numbers. You don't need `binascii`.

```
hex_input  = 'C0A80026'
dec_output = [
    int(hex_input[0:2], 16), int(hex_input[2:4], 16),
    int(hex_input[4:6], 16), int(hex_input[6:8], 16),
]
print dec_output # [192, 168, 0, 38]
```

This can be generalised, but I'll leave it as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 9):

A simple way

```
>>> s = 'C0A80026'
>>> map(ord, s.decode('hex'))
[192, 168, 0, 38]
>>>
```

if you prefer list comprehensions

```
>>> [ord(c) for c in s.decode('hex')]
[192, 168, 0, 38]
>>>
```

Comment: Nice one.  I'd _personally_ write it as a list comprehension, but that is purely taste.  I like the use of `decode` and `ord`.

Answer (score 5):

You might also need the chr function:

```
chr(65) => 'A'
```

Comment: chr accepts only integers the question states clearly that the user needs to convert a hex in an int/char (not an int to char) and chr accepts only integers so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> htext='C0A80026'
>>> [int(htext[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(htext),2)]
# [192, 168, 0, 38]
```

Answer (score 3):

For converting hex-string to human readable string you can escape every HEX character like this:

```
>>> '\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
'hello'
```

from string you can easily loop to INT list:

```
>>> hextoint = [ord(c) for c in '\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f']
>>> _
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Your example:

```
>>> [ord(c) for c in '\xC0\xA8\x00\x26']
[192, 168, 0, 38]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's what you expect:

```
hex_val = 0x42424242     # hexadecimal value
int_val = int(hex_val)   # integer value
str_val = str(int_val)   # string representation of integer value
```

Comment: Literal `0x4242422` already creates an integer, `int(hex_val)` is redundant.