# Python - Reading BLOB type from SQLite3 DB

Tags: python, sqlite, binary, hex

This is a follow on from: [Python - Converting Hex to INT/CHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595148/python-converting-hex-to-int-char)

I now have a working solution for converting the stored hex value of an IP from an sqlite3 db into a readable and usable format. However up until now I have been testing by copying and pasting the values directly from a sqlite3 db viewer.

I have been trying to poll the db with a script to lookup that information however I have discovered that it apparantly stores blob data into a buffer which isn't instantly human readable.

For example, the IP 192.168.0.1 is stored as blob type under the field ip as X'C0A80001'

Since I worked from a copied and pasted example into my code I have constructed code to strip the X' and ' from the hex to be able to then convert it. What I cannot get is that value from the database (X'C0A80001' <- this value that I can view with a db manager).
Searching I found http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/05/29/storing-blobs-in-a-sqlite-db-with-pythonpysqlite/ which showed an example of reading blobs to and from a sqlite db but their methods didn't work. They displayed the error;

> ```
> print row[0], str(row[1]).encode('hex')
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
> ```

I am fairly new to Python so apologies if I am missing something basic but any pointers or code examples anyone has to help me get my head around this would  be appreciated.

EDIT:
Doh, didn't paste the code from the above example;

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select ip from item where name = ' + "\'" + host + "\'")
for row in c:
        print row[0], str(row[1]).encode('hex')
```

It may be my understanding thats really off here as to why I can't read it back the way I want to

UPDATE:
Using the below answer I modified my code to;

```
rows = c.execute('select ip from item where name= ' + "\"" + host + "\"") 
   for row in rows:
       print str(row[0]).encode("hex")
```

Comment: You store IP addresses in your DB, but only IPv4 ones. What about IPv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the link, it seems the most likely explanation is an empty row. On line 29 you set up a for loop to go over the results of a query. In python this means you have a list:
`[item,item2,item3]` and each time you go through the loop, your `row` variable points to the next item.

Within the loop, you are checking the *contents* of the current item. Each of these items is a tuple which suppposedly has at least two entries. But if any of those items don't have an entry for `row[0]` or `row[1]` then you will get an index out of range exception.

You haven't posted enough code to make determining *why* this occurred feasible, but to get the code running I'd suggest this:

```
for row in cur.execute("select * from frames"):
    try:
        print row[0], str(row[1]).encode('hex') 
    except IndexError, e:
        print "IndexError: {0}".format(e)
```

That will continue across your entire query result, even if some of them are bad.

*Edit:* I just saw your update, and your problem is that c does not hold the contents of your query. `c.execute('select ip from item where name = ' + "\'" + host + "\'")` returns a list, which you ignore.

The original example works because you get the list in the for loop, and so it's an anonymous variable *only within the loop context*. To fix your code:

```
c = conn.cursor()
rows = c.execute('select ip from item where name = ' + "\'" + host + "\'")
for row in rows:
        print row[0], str(row[1]).encode('hex')
```

Comment: Thank you! I was being very simple. So the IP field is the third field in the table and so what I needed to do was access row[2] using your modification of getting the list. I will edit my above question to include my final working solution for completeness. Thank you again.

Comment: @Draineh no problem. I'd suggest going through [the python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) or at least skimming your way up to chapter 9. That will explain various python constructs, such as lists and looping. It doesn't take too long, and you'll save yourself a lot of headache.

Comment: Just had "Python - Essential Reference" arrive through the post so hopefully I should be able to get some decent learning done.

Comment: `c.execute('select ip from item where name = ' + "\'" + host + "\'")` is bad style. Better would be `c.execute('select ip from item where name = ?', host)` where I don't know if sqlite wants a `?` or a `%s` as MySQL wants.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks, I had read somewhere that it was good practice to use ? for sqlite interaction in Python but through my debugging I'd just been trying to get the basics working - I will change it over