# How can I access Firefox's internal indexedDB files using Python?

Tags: python, firefox, indexeddb

I need to read firefox's indexeddb using python.

I use `slite3` package to retrieve contents of indexeddb:

```
with sqlite3.connect(indexeddb_file) as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from object_data;')
    rows = c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row[2]
```

However, although I know that contents in database are strings, they are stored as sqlite [binary blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846013/how-to-view-indexeddb-content-in-firefox). Is there a way to read the strings stored as blobs from python?

I've tried:

- [hex() and quote()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597736/python-reading-blob-type-from-sqlite3-db) sql methods just encode the blob to hexadecimal
- the same problem when I [write the blob to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435072/sqlite-how-to-castdata-as-text-for-blob)

**UPDATE**

Following the coding scheme in firefox [source code](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/dom/indexedDB/Key.cpp) of the implementation of indexeddb pointed out by @paa in one of the comments of this question, I implemented part of FF encoding method for database keys in python. So, far I have implemented it only for strings but implementing it for other types would be even easier:

```
BYTE_LENGTH = 8

def hex_to_bin(hex_str):
    """Return binary representation of hexadecimal string."""
    return str(trim_bin(int(hex_str, 16)).zfill(len(hex_str) * 4))

def byte_to_unicode(bin_byte):
    """Return unicode encoding for binary byte."""
    return chr(int(str(bin_byte), 2))

def trim_bin(int_n):
    """Return int num converted to trimmed bin representation."""
    return bin(int_n)[2:]

def decode(key):
    """Return decoded idb key."""
    decoded = key
    m = re.search("[1-9]", key)  # change for non-zero
    if m:
        i = m.start()
        typeoffset = int(key[i])
    else:
        # error
        pass
    data = key[i + 1:]
    if typeoffset is 1:
        # decode number
        pass
    elif typeoffset is 2:
        # decode date
        pass
    elif typeoffset is 3:
        # decode string
        bin_repr = hex_to_bin(data)
        decoded = ""
        for i in xrange(0, len(bin_repr), BYTE_LENGTH):
            byte = bin_repr[i:i + BYTE_LENGTH]
            if byte[0] is '0':
                byte_1 = int(byte, 2) - 1
                decoded += byte_to_unicode(trim_bin(byte_1))
            else:
                byte = byte[2:]
                if byte[1] is '0':
                    byte_127 = int(byte, 2) + 127
                    decoded += byte_to_unicode(trim_bin(byte_127))
                    i += BYTE_LENGTH
                    decoded += byte_to_unicode(bin_repr[i:i + BYTE_LENGTH])
                elif byte[1] is '1':
                    decoded += byte_to_unicode(byte)
                    i += BYTE_LENGTH
                    decoded += byte_to_unicode(bin_repr[i:i + BYTE_LENGTH])
                    i += BYTE_LENGTH
                    decoded += byte_to_unicode(bin_repr[i:i + 2])
        return decoded
    elif typeoffset is 4:
        # decode array
        pass
    else:
        # error
        pass
    return decoded
```

However, I'm still not able to decode the data fields of indexeddb. It seems to me that they are not using any sophisticated scheme like the one for the keys because I can read some parts of the actual values when I encode them in UTF-16.

Comment: I suspect that firefox's implementation encrypts indexeddb data but I cannot find it in their source code. Here is the method that is responsible for inserting a new record into the database: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-aurora/source/dom/indexedDB/IDBObjectStore.cpp#1594 (from http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2012-10-05-indexeddb-storage.html)

Comment: From https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/: `In Firefox’s IndexedDB implementation (and I believe IE’s too) the files are transparently stored outside of the actual database.` I was wrong they probably do not encrypt it. The problem could be: `Firefox IndexedDB implementation is even smart enough that if you store the same Blob multiple files in a IndexedDB database it just creates one copy of the file.`

Comment: The contents are not encrypted, but they are encoded. You will find this [helpful](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/dom/indexedDB/Key.cpp)

Comment: @Kits89 if you figure it out before I do please post your answer! And better yet, double post with an email to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/indexeddb-users

Comment: I'm able to decode idb keys following the specs provided by @paa. However, it seems that for data they're using a different scheme...

Comment: Can you publish a gist or something to share what you've got? I'm really fascinate by your ask and wouldn't mind poking around myself.

Comment: sure, I'll edit the question an update it. I won't answer myself because I still cannot decode the data of the sqlite but I'll explain my findings

Comment: Here's the updated repository link that @paa had mentioned [1]. They have a bit more info regarding the custom encoding that they're using. I don't have a lot of time right now, but I'll see if I can grok the source and OP's code to see if I can come up with something useful; I'm interested in this working, given that---on an update---I was left without access to my previous OneTab bookmarks [2]. 

[1] https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/dom/indexedDB
[2] https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1261474

Answer (score 1):

(Typing here since I can't comment yet...)

For data itself I've been trying to do the same thing for data blobs. For my problem, I'm trying to grab JSON strings out. If I look at the DB I'm trying to sift through, I do see UTF-16 encoded characters, most of the time. But there are strange cases where I have this:

"there we go" is encoded as 7400 6800 6500 7200 6500 2000 77 [05060C] 6700 6F00. The [05060C] supposedly encodes "e ".

https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/dom/indexedDB/IDBObjectStore.cpp

I'm trying to look into that and see if there are any clues. Should be plenty of other source files in the directory that could help.