# Printing wrong text in list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, beautifulsoup

This is My Code.

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = req.get('https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+0900')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
myunicode = soup.select('.uid')
myunicodes = [myunicodes.text for myunicodes in myunicode]
res = [sub.replace('+', 'u') for sub in myunicodes]
res = [sub.replace('U', '') for sub in res]
list = ['\\' + item for item in res]
print(list)
```

When I am trying to add backslash `\` in the list of strings with the following code.
 `list = ['\\' + item for item in res]` This Will remove `+` From the list and add '\\' in the starting of the code. I am also tried with `r'\\'` But this is not worked for me. Please Help me to Solvee this. Here is What I got.

```
['\\u0900', '\\u0901', '\\u0902', '\\u0903', '\\u0904', '\\u0905', '\\u0906', '\\u0907', '\\u0908', '\\u0909', '\\u090A', '\\u090B', '\\u090C', '\\u090D', '\\u090E', '\\u090F', '\\u0910', '\\u0911', '\\u0912', '\\u0913', '\\u0914', '\\u0915', '\\u0916', '\\u0917', '\\u0918', '\\u0919', '\\u091A', '\\u091B', '\\u091C', '\\u091D', '\\u091E', '\\u091F', '\\u0920', '\\u0921', '\\u0922', '\\u0923', '\\u0924', '\\u0925', '\\u0926', '\\u0927', '\\u0928', '\\u0929', '\\u092A', '\\u092B', '\\u092C', '\\u092D', '\\u092E', '\\u092F', '\\u0930', '\\u0931', '\\u0932', '\\u0933', '\\u0934', '\\u0935', '\\u0936', '\\u0937', '\\u0938', '\\u0939', '\\u093A', '\\u093B', '\\u093C', '\\u093D', '\\u093E', '\\u093F', '\\u0940', '\\u0941', '\\u0942', '\\u0943', '\\u0944', '\\u0945', '\\u0946', '\\u0947', '\\u0948', '\\u0949', '\\u094A', '\\u094B', '\\u094C', '\\u094D', '\\u094E', '\\u094F', '\\u0950', '\\u0951', '\\u0952', '\\u0953', '\\u0954', '\\u0955', '\\u0956', '\\u0957', '\\u0958', '\\u0959', '\\u095A', '\\u095B', '\\u095C', '\\u095D', '\\u095E', '\\u095F', '\\u0960', '\\u0961', '\\u0962', '\\u0963', '\\u0964', '\\u0965', '\\u0966', '\\u0967', '\\u0968', '\\u0969', '\\u096A', '\\u096B', '\\u096C', '\\u096D', '\\u096E', '\\u096F', '\\u0970', '\\u0971', '\\u0972', '\\u0973', '\\u0974', '\\u0975', '\\u0976', '\\u0977', '\\u0978', '\\u0979', '\\u097A', '\\u097B', '\\u097C', '\\u097D', '\\u097E', '\\u097F']
```

Here What is Expected .

```
# Need All the Strings Like the Following
['\u097E', '\u097F',] # Need All the Codes...
```

Thanks For Your Help in Advance ! ❤️

Comment: Escape sequences are only processed on program literals. They're not processed when you create strings in code.

Comment: Can you tell me How to Solve it ???

Comment: On last example you have escape sequence, there is no `u` or `0` or `9` or `7` or `e` characters, so it is not the string you are in mind. Maybe you are looking something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595148/python-converting-hex-to-int-char

Comment: Python 3 won't display `['\u097e','\u097f']`.  It will display that list as `['ॾ', 'ॿ']`.  So do you want Unicode escapes instead of code points?  That's what `['\\u097e','\\u097f']` is.  A literal single backslash is always displayed in a list as `'\\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is as i should be:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = req.get('https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+0900')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
myunicode = soup.select('.uid')
myunicodes = [myunicodes.text for myunicodes in myunicode]
res = [sub.replace('+', 'u') for sub in myunicodes]
res = [sub.replace('U', '') for sub in res]
list = ['\\' + item for item in res]
for l in list:
    print(l)
```

Outputs:

```
\u0900
\u0901
\u0902
\u0903
\u0904
\u0905
\u0906
```

Comment: This is for printing how can I store them all in a list.

Comment: @N1NG4 They are stored in a list.  Lists just display strings using the `repr()` function.  Printing uses `str()`.  `repr()` escapes backslashes and unprintable characters.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen The repr() and str() functions are not printing right text. Please share with me the printing method. Please Help me Last Time 

Comment: @N1NG4 Update your question. "Not printing right text" doesn't explain your issue.