# Is their any python3 function to convert hexadecimal no to decimal no directly?

Tags: python-3.x, hex

Does their any function exist in python3 which can convert hexadecimal no into decimal no directly??(like their exists bin,oct,etc. function in python3..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful information is available in the following post: [How do I convert hex to decimal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210525/how-do-i-convert-hex-to-decimal-in-python)

Cheers!