# How do I convert the contents of a byte[] array from hex to decimal?

Tags: java, arrays, hex, decimal

I have a targetDataLine open...

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[line.getBufferSize() / 5];
line.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

The bytes array is in hex, how do I get it's contents to be represented as decimal values?

Comment: It is generally helpful if you add the language you're using as a tag (where you wrote `arrays`, `hex` and `decimal` you would also write the name of the language you are using). I think this is java?

Comment: It's in java! sorry forgot to include that

Comment: By hex you mean a character stream like "af4b26d3" or binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int decValue = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

Resources: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of the OP's posting language.

In Python, if you have an array and you want to get the decimal values of the bytes, you could loop through and use ord() to get the decimal representation.

If you had to convert from an actual array containing hex values, then you can do the conversion as per this StackOverflow posting:

[Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: I assumed java because the only other questions they have are java

Comment: It's java, sorry I forgot to include that!