# How to convert hex string 'o\xf2\x00\x00' into a int32?

Tags: python, int, hex

When I read first 4 bytes with python code

```
len = fobj.read(4)
```

I got `'o\xf2\x00\x00'`. This should be an `int32`, and when I read the file with other tool (`matlab`, for example), it gives `62063`.

Could anybody give any hints on how I can convert the `hex` string into an `int` in python?

I've read [this hex string to int conversion discussion,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python) but found no help.

Thank you for any suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('<i', 'o\xf2\x00\x00')
(62063,)
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Made it explicitly little-endian now

Comment: Thank you so much jamylak, for your prompt and helpful reply!

Answer (score 1):

I Tried this and got the answer:

```
>>> print(int.from_bytes(b'o\xf2\x00\x00','little'))
62063
```