# Generating k numbers of hash value with python

Tags: python, hash

I need to generate k numbers of hash value (0 .. m-1), and k numbers should be distinct.
The hash values should be different based on different hash seed.

I found this code, but it's too big for me to use with only one value.

```
import hashlib, uuid
password = "abc" <-- key
salt = str(10) # <-- hash seed 
value = hashlib.sha1(password + salt).hexdigest()
print value # 105dee46d56df0c97ca9b6a09e59fbf63d8ceae2
```

How can I get good k hash values between 0 and m-1? Or is it just OK to split the value into k parts to apply mod operation?

Comment: are you trying to make it work with a variable `m` number ? or is it a specific m?

Comment: ... are you trying to produce a hash collision or something?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It can be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [mmh3](https://github.com/hajimes/mmh3) is the best option so far.

```
import mmh3

def getHash(key, m, k):
    result = set()
    seed = 1
    while True:
        if len(result) == k:
            return list(result)
        else:
            b = mmh3.hash(key, seed) % m
            result.add(b)
            seed += 10
            print result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print getHash("Hello", 100, 5)
    print getHash("Good Bye", 100, 5)
```

Result:

```
set([12])
set([43, 12])
set([43, 12, 29])
set([88, 43, 12, 29])
set([88, 80, 43, 12, 29])
[88, 80, 43, 12, 29]
set([20])
set([2, 20])
set([2, 20, 70])
set([2, 75, 20, 70])
set([2, 75, 20, 70, 39])
[2, 75, 20, 70, 39]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear with regards to what "k" and "m" are.  But all bits of any reasonable hash function output are equally "random".  So you can chop it up and use pieces separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works.

```
import hashlib, uuid
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python

def getHash(key, hashseed, m, k):
    """
    We use sha256, and it generates 64 bytes of hash number, so k should be 2 <= k <= 32
    However, because of duplicity the real limit should be much lower.

    Todo: You can concatenate more sha256 values to get more k values
    """
    salt = str(hashseed)
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(key + salt).hexdigest()
    if k > 32: raise Error("k should be less than 32")
    if k <= 1: raise Error("k should be more than 2")

    result = []
    index = 0

    # make the non-overwrapping hash value below m
    while True:
        value = int(hashed_password[index:index+2], 16) % m
        index += 2

        # second loop for detecting the duplicate value
        while True:
            if value not in result:
                result.append(value)
                break
            # Try the next value
            value = int(hashed_password[index:index+2], 16) % m
            index += 2
        if len(result) == k: break

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
  res = getHash("abc", 1, 10, 5) # seed:1, m = 10, k = 5
  assert len(res) == 5
```