# How to convert a hex string to hex number

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex

I want to convert a hex string (ex: `0xAD4`) to hex number, then to add `0x200` to that number and again want to print that number in form of `0x` as a string.

i tried for the first step:

```
str(int(str(item[1][:-2]),16))
```

but the value that is getting printed is a decimal string not a hex formatted string (in 0x format) ( i want to print the final result in form of `0x`)

- `[:-2]` to remove the last 00 from that number
- `item[1]` is containing hex number in form of `0x`

Comment: There's no such thing in Python as a hex number. There's just numbers. So you want to convert a hex string to a number, not to a hex number, then you want to print a number as hex.

Comment: @SteveJessop your comment is answer, and both answer are comment :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: no, it's not an answer. The question contains a misconception, but after correcting that misconception the question still stands and my comment doesn't answer it. The answers do.

Comment: @SteveJessop yes but I think the important point that should be explained in answer that hex is just representation all numbers stores in same ways(that you says) And hence there is no difference between `2772` and `0XAD4`. So if `i = 0XAD4` then `print i` will outputs `2772` but not `ad4` OP need to use `%x`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209513/608639)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Try this:

```
hex_str = "0xAD4"
hex_int = int(hex_str, 16)
new_int = hex_int + 0x200
print hex(new_int)
```

If you don't like the `0x` in the beginning, replace the last line with

```
print hex(new_int)[2:]
```

Comment: I like to be more explicit: `int(hex_str, base=16)` rather than `int(hex_str, 16)`. Note that the documentation for `int()` is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 20):

Use [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function with second parameter 16, to convert a hex string to an integer. Finally, use [`hex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) function to convert it back to a hexadecimal number.

```
print hex(int("0xAD4", 16) + int("0x200", 16)) # 0xcd4
```

Instead you could directly do

```
print hex(int("0xAD4", 16) + 0x200) # 0xcd4
```

Comment: I believe OP's confusing is that he differentiates between `i = 0xad4` and `i = 2772` when he prints `i`. (and seems when I reads his thanks) Anyways + to both of you as I didn't now `hex( )`

Answer (score 0):

Use format string

```
intNum = 123
print "0x%x"%(intNum)
```

or `hex` function.

```
intNum = 123
print hex(intNum)
```

Comment: It looks like reciprocal OP wants "string to hex-digit", But your answer is "number to a hex string"!!

Comment: You can improve answer by adding the fact that hex-number preceding with `0x` is just for user convenience Every number stores in binary not even in decimal.

Comment: I think he wants to convert integer number to hex string. Because he has already converted hex string to integer number.

Comment: Read title, Read question, notice his statement question   *`'but it is only converting that number to int not in hex'`*.  That the reason second time commented you.

Comment: Ah, You mean he is misunderstanding String as Number?

Comment: No OP think `i = 2772` and `j = 0xad4` are two different things.

Comment: i have updated the question. looks like it is more clear now. anyway i got the answer.