# Python pass input string which has spaces and use for smbus

Tags: python, smbus

My code for ic2 is.

```
import argparse
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

bus.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x00, 0x00)
bus.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x01, 0x00)
bus.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0x01)    
time.sleep(0.5) 
bus.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x12, 0x00)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

It work fine.

And I test this code.

```
import argparse
import sys
var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]
print 'Params=', var1, var2, var3
```

By

```
python test.py  0x20 0x14 0x01
Params= 0x20 0x14 0x01
```

But when I try code to.

```
import argparse
import sys
import smbus
import time

var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

bus.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x00, 0x00)
bus.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x01, 0x00)
bus.write_byte_data(var1, var2, var3)    
time.sleep(0.5) 
bus.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x12, 0x00)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

python test.py  0x20 0x14 0x01

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in 
    bus.write_byte_data(var1, var2, var3)
TypeError: an integer is required

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to make what you are asking more clear to everyone. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve and what you expect.

Comment: Please guide me for this question I don't know how to asked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument values look like HEX. Are you calling this via batch or bash?  Python can distinguish HEX and decimal automatically, batch/bash can not.

In this case, although you submit HEX to `sys.argv[x]`, bash/batch thinks it's a string and submits the string to python. Therefore, you need to [convert to HEX int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21879510/6060083) explicitly.

```
var1 = int(sys.argv[1], 16) # The '16' defines the base here
var2 = int(sys.argv[2], 16) # Base '16' converts HEX string to HEX int
var3 = int(sys.argv[3], 16) # You must set base to '16' here
```

NB: If you want a non-HEX int number ('normal' integer), you can convert by using base `0` rather than `16` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)).

Comment: Ok that work fine.
If I want to in put only var3 in 0000 0001 (8bit)
Maybe possible?
lookike
python test.py  20 14 00000001

OK I just test var3 = int(sys.argv[3], 2) that ok.

Thanks