# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' for

Tags: python, regex, typeerror, quantifiers

I am using python 3.7

My list data looks like this

```
[['file1.o', '.text', '0x30'], ['file2.o', '.initvector', '0x36'], ['15', '31', '0x72']]
```

My code

For parsing the file

```
 c = re.compile("^\w+.*(\w+)\s+([\.\w]+)\s+([\w\.]+).*$")
```

Printing to a csv file uses

```
 for i in module_info:
    row = [i[0], i[1], "%d" %(i[2]/1024)]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I am getting this error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

How can I fix this?

I have updated the answer. Appreciate all contributions

Comment: You're trying to divid **strings** such as `'0x30'` to 1024. It's not clear what are you trying to do, you don't provide enough context about what you're trying to achieve which makes it impossible to help you.

Comment: Yeah correct. I wanted to get hex value in KBytes that is why. Problem is that the 0x30 is being treated as string and not hex no. Even if i remove divide by 1024. I get "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a hex string to hex number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879454/how-to-convert-a-hex-string-to-hex-number)

Comment: The [accepted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21879510/1057429) is doing exactly the same as the answer  you've accepted here: `int(hex_str, 16)` :)

Comment: Also, the update that you posted does not explain how this code change provides the hex number in decimal, divide by 1024. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is generating in `i[2]/1024` this snippet of code, where the `i[2]` is actually interpreted as a string and `1024` as an int. That's why the error is there.

You have to convert the string into a number

To convert the hex string into a decimal number, use `int(i[2], 16)`

To convert the hex string into a decimal number, use `bin(int(i[2], 16))`

Use your preferred type of conversion and use it. I hope that'll solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the second-index elements are hexadecimal integers, you can use the `int()` function and pass `16` (base 16) as the second argument.

```py
for i in module_info:
    row = [i[0], i[1], "%d" % (int(i[2], 16) / 1024)]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

When looping through the list and printing `row`:

```py
>>> for i in lst:
        row = [i[0], i[1], "%d" % (int(i[2], 16) / 1024)]
        print(row)

    
['file1.o', '.text', '0']
['file2.o', '.initvector', '0']
['15', '31', '0']
```

The second element of `row` in each iteration is `"0"` because the `"%d"` placeholder inserts `(int(i[2], 16) / 1024)` as an integer. I would recommend just inserting as a string (use `"%s"`) if you want the full decimal representation.

```py
>>> for i in lst:
        row = [i[0], i[1], "%s" % (int(i[2], 16) / 1024)]
        print(row)

    
['file1.o', '.text', '0.046875']
['file2.o', '.initvector', '0.052734375']
['15', '31', '0.111328125']
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts in answering my question. I found another way that solves my problem by reading the data correctly during file parsing. I will update my question with appropriate comments.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I was parsing the file and reading its contents. I attempted to use greedy quantifier when I just needed to strip the "origin+".

```
#regex input format     Origin+Size        Section          Module
#                       800a1010+000c7c    .Code.Cpu0       Adc.o    #old line

 c = re.compile("^\w+.*(\w+)\s+([\.\w]+)\s+([\w\.]+).*$")

 #new line
 c = re.compile("^\w+\+(\w+)\s+([\.\w]+)\s+([\w\.]+).*$")
```

so now writing to file changes to this

```
for i in module_info:
    row = [i[0], i[1], (i[2])]
    writer.writerow(row)
```

> Also, the update that you posted does not explain how this code change provides the hex number in decimal, divide by 1024. Care to elaborate?

division with 1024 was just to get the value in KiloBytes, while changing from hex to decimal. I decide to drop that and do such operations in excel.

[Reference discussion on quantifiers that i got benefit from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions)

Does this answer your question? How to convert a hex string to hex number

> Does this answer your question? [How to convert a hex string to hex number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879454/how-to-convert-a-hex-string-to-hex-number)

Yes it does. I see it in a new light now.

Answer (score -1):

`i[2]` is a string unless it looks like number. Try:

```
row = [i[0], i[1], "%d" %(int(i[2])/1024)]
```

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x30'`

Comment: Int(i[2], base=16)