# Is there a simple way to convert between bytes and their hex representations (also bytes) in python, like '\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d' to '1a2b3c4d'?

Tags: python, string, byte

Is there a ***simple*** way (or simplest?) to convert between `'\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d'` and `'1a2b3c4d'` in **python**?

(Here `'\x4d'` means a byte whose ascii code is `4d`, namely the character `'M'`, but `'4d'` stand for two characters. And the others are similar meanings.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: @importV, they're actually not the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert bytes to their hex representation with the [`binascii.hexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d')
'1a2b3c4d'
```