# Convert two character string to its hex value in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to convert `"0d"` to `0xd` or `"ff"` to `0xff`.

I have tried `hex("0d")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do base conversion as `16`, the second operand to `int` takes the base value of the number you need to convert

```
>>> a = "0d"
>>> int(a,16)
13
>>> hex(int(a,16))
'0xd'
>>> a = "ff"
>>> int(a,16)
255
>>> hex(int(a,16))
'0xff'
```