# Python "ValueError"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got everything working now but i get an error.

Console Error:

```
PS C:\Python\Artinis> python sort.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort.py", line 66, in <module>
    if int(Config.get(section, 'name')) < sn_low:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5DB7'
```

Python Code:

```
import ConfigParser

Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
ConfigNew = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

oxymon = []
portamon = []
portalite = []

follow = 0
index = 0
sn_low = 0

#Config.read("c:\\Python\\Artinis\\portasoft.ini")
Config.read("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Artinis Medical Systems BV\\common\\portasoft.ini")

for section in Config.sections():
    if "Device" in section:
        #print section
        #print Config.items(section)
        #print Config.options(section)
        name = Config.get(section, 'name')
        type = Config.get(section, 'type')
        if "OXYMON" in type:
            oxymon.append(section)
        elif "PORTAMON" in type:
            portamon.append(section)
        elif "PORTALITE" in type:
            portalite.append(section)   

#Maakt een lijst van alles wat is niet "Device".
    else: 
        ConfigNew.add_section(section)
        for item in Config.items(section):
            ConfigNew.set(section, item[0], item[1])

""""#Sorteer functies#"""
#Sorteert Oxymon op "name".
'''
for loop in oxymon:
    index = 0
    for section in oxymon:
        if index == follow:
            sn_low = int(Config.get(section, 'name'))

        if index > follow:
            if int(Config.get(section, 'name')) < sn_low:
                sn_low = Config.get(section, 'name')
                oxymon_temp = oxymon[index]
                oxymon[index] = oxymon[follow]
                oxymon[follow] = oxymon_temp

        index = index + 1

    follow = follow + 1
'''

#Sorteert Portamon op "name".
for loop in portamon:
    index = 0
    for section in portamon:
        if index == follow:
            sn_low = int(Config.get(section, 'name'))

        if index > follow:
            if int(Config.get(section, 'name')) < sn_low:
                sn_low = Config.get(section, 'name')
                portamon_temp = portamon[index]
                portamon[index] = portamon[follow]
                portamon[follow] = portamon_temp

        index = index + 1

    follow = follow + 1

#Sorteert Portalite op "name".
for loop in portalite:
    index = 0
    for section in portalite:
        if index == follow:
            sn_low = int(Config.get(section, 'name'))

        if index > follow:
            if int(Config.get(section, 'name')) < sn_low:
                sn_low = Config.get(section, 'name')
                portalite_temp = portalite[index]
                portalite[index] = portalite[follow]
                portalite[follow] = portalite_temp

        index = index + 1

    follow = follow + 1

"""#Functies om te printen#"""
index = 0

print ""
#Print Oxymon.
for section in oxymon:
    ConfigNew.add_section('Device%r' % index)
    for item in Config.items(section):
        ConfigNew.set('Device%r' % index, item[0], item[1])
    index = index + 1
    print "> Oxymon"
    print "> -%r" % section
    print "> -%r" % Config.get(section, 'name')
    #print Config.get(section, 'type')
print ""

#Print Portamon.
for section in portamon:
    ConfigNew.add_section('Device%r' % index)
    for item in Config.items(section):
        ConfigNew.set('Device%r' % index, item[0], item[1])
    index = index + 1
    print "> Portamon"
    print "> -%r" % section
    print "> -%r" % Config.get(section, 'name')
    #print Config.get(section, 'type')
print ""

#Print Portalite.
for section in portalite:
    ConfigNew.add_section('Device%r' % index)
    for item in Config.items(section):
        ConfigNew.set('Device%r' % index, item[0], item[1])
    index = index + 1
    print "> Portalite"
    print "> -%r" % section
    print "> -%r" % Config.get(section, 'name')
    #print Config.get(section, 'type')
print ""

"""#Functies om te schrijven#"""
#Alles voor "Device*" schrijven.
with open('portasoft_new.ini', 'wb') as configfile:
    ConfigNew.write(configfile)
```

It sorts from this file.

```
[Admin]
ShowTools=1
ShowMeasurements=0

[Test]
Test=Test
[Session]
Name=06124
Location=C:\Users\Djordy\Desktop\Dump\

[Comms]
Port=COM140

[Asciiwriter]
Enable=1

[Device0]
Name=AnyOxymon
Type = OXYMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_VOXY
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
PhysicalLayerPort=
PhysicalLayerParams=1250000,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CTS

[Device1]
Name = 203 
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
;PhysicalLayer=PL_VIRTUALCOMM
;PhysicalLayerPort=COM43
;PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B20
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device2]
Name = 207
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
Name = 207
PhysicalLayerPort=000666003BEC
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device3]
Name = 209
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
;PhysicalLayer=PL_VIRTUALCOMM
;PhysicalLayerPort=COM20
;PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=0006660039CB
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device4]
Name = 210
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066600A620
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device5]
Name = 211
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=0006660039DB
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device6]
Name = 212
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066600A630
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device7]
Name = 213
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B11
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device8]
Name = 214
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B12
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device9]
Name = 215
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B09
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device10]
Name = 218
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B0F
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device11]
Name = 219
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DC2
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device12]
Name = 220
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DC6
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device13]
Name = 221
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DD2
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device14]
Name = 5DB7
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DB7
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device15]
Name = 223
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666016574
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device16]
Name = 224
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DD3
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device17]
Name = 225
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DB6
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device18]
Name = 226
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066601656F
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device19]
Name = 227
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DE5
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device20]
Name = 228
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DD6
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device21]
Name = 229
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DD7
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device22]
Name = 230
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066601656B
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device23]
Name = 231
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DB4
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device24]
Name = 232
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666015DC5
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device25]
Name = 233
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666016570
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device26]
Name = FEF1
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A09618FEF1
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device27]
Name = A5FF
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066600A5FF
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device28]
Name = 4B15
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B15
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device29]
Name = A610
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066600A610
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1


[Device30]
Name = 3BEA
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=000666003BEA
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device31]
Name=Portamon 200
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_UART
PhysicalLayerPort=COM2
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device32]
Name=AdBox
Type = ADBOX
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_VOXY
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
PhysicalLayerPort=
PhysicalLayerParams=1250000,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CTS

[Device33]
Name=VC820
Type=VC820
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_VC820
CodingLayer=CL_TIMEDPACKET
CodingLayerParams=200, 14
PhysicalLayer=PL_UART
PhysicalLayerPort=COM2
PhysicalLayerParams=2400,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE + FLOW_DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE

[Device34]
Name=SignalGenerator
Type=SIGNALGENERATOR
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_SIGNALGEN
CodingLayer=CL_DUMMY
PhysicalLayer=PL_DUMMY
PhysicalLayerPort=
PhysicalLayerParams=

[Device35]
Name=PortaProto_CCD
Type=PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_PORTAPROTO
CodingLayer=CL_MAGIC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066600D68C
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1
;PhysicalLayer=PL_VIRTUALCOMM
;PhysicalLayerPort=COM82
;PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device36]
;Name=Digiflow
;Type=SIGNALGENERATOR
;Enabled=0
;MessageLayer=ML_DIGIFLOW
;CodingLayer=CL_TIMEDPACKET
;CodingLayerParams=50,55
;PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
;PhysicalLayerPort=
;PhysicalLayerParams=250000,n,8,1
Name=AnyOxymon
Type = OXYMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_VOXY
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
PhysicalLayerPort=
PhysicalLayerParams=1250000,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CTS

[Device37]
Name=AnyOxymon
Type = OXYMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_VOXY
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
PhysicalLayerPort=
PhysicalLayerParams=1250000,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CTS

[Device38]
Name=AdBox_4103
Type = OXYMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_VOXY
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
PhysicalLayerPort=AMS04103
PhysicalLayerParams=1250000,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CTS

[Device39]
Name=Oxymon_95
Type = OXYMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_VOXY
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
PhysicalLayerPort=AMS095
PhysicalLayerParams=1250000,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CTS

[Device40]
Name = 201
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B16
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device41]
Name = 205
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
Name = 207
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B5A
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device42]
Name=Oxymon_VoxyDirect
Type = OXYMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_DUMMY
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_FTDI
PhysicalLayerPort=
PhysicalLayerParams=1250000,n,8,1,FLOW_RTS_CTS

[Device43]
Name = 234
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_VIRTUALCOMM
PhysicalLayerPort=COM40
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device44]
Name = 235
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_VIRTUALCOMM
PhysicalLayerPort=COM41
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device45]
Name = 236
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D702
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device46]
Name = 237
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D701
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device47]
Name = 238
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D721
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device48]
Name = 239
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=0006660A305B
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device49]
Name = 240
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D714
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device50]
Name = 241
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D722
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device51]
Name = 242
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D6FD
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device52]
Name = 243
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D703
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device53]
Name = 244
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D6F3
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device54]
Name = 245
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D712
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device55]
Name = 246
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D711
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device56]
Name = 247
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00066602D6F2
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device57]
Name = 204
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled=0
MessageLayer=ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer=CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer=PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort=00A096134B1C
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device58]
Name = 249
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f201
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device59]
Name = 250
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f211
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device60]
Name = 251
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f212
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device61]
Name = 252
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f233
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device62]
Name = 253
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f232
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device63]
Name = 254
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f22f
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device64]
Name = 255
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort =00066602f221
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device65]
Name = 256
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f202
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device66]
Name = 257
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f230
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device67]
Name = 258
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f20f
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device68]
Name = 259
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f213
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device69]
Name = 260
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f203
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device70]
Name = 261
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f200
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device71]
Name = 262
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f231
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device72]
Name = 263
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f222
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device73]
Name = 265
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort =00066602f220
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device74]
Name = 266
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602f210
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device75]
Name = 268
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607ACFA
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device76]
Name = 269
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607ACFE
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device77]
Name = 270
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD01
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device78]
Name = 271
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD02
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device79]
Name = 272
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD03
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device80]
Name = 273
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD04
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device81]
Name = 274
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD05
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device82]
Name = 275
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD06
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device83]
Name = 276
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD08
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device84]
Name = 277
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_IOCTL
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066607AD09
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device85]
Name = WheightScale
Type = VC820
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_WHEIGHTSCALE
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort =  00066604A6E5
PhysicalLayerParams=62500,n,8,1

[Device86]
Name = WheightScale
Type = VC820
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_WHEIGHTSCALE
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort =  00066604A6E1
PhysicalLayerParams=62500,n,8,1

[Device87]
Name = WheightScale
Type = VC820
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_WHEIGHTSCALE
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort =  00066604A6E3
PhysicalLayerParams=62500,n,8,1

[Device88]
Name = WheightScale
Type = VC820
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_WHEIGHTSCALE
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort =  000666033f51
PhysicalLayerParams=62500,n,8,1

[Device89]
Name = WheightScale
Type = VC820
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_WHEIGHTSCALE
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066602D704
PhysicalLayerParams=62500,n,8,1

[Device90]
Name = DummyDevice
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_DUMMYDEVICE
CodingLayer = CL_DUMMY
PhysicalLayer = PL_DUMMY
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066604A6E2
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1

[Device91]
Name = PortamonLpc
Type = PORTAMON
Enabled =0
MessageLayer = ML_FORMATDESCRIPTOR
CodingLayer = CL_HDLC
PhysicalLayer = PL_BTSOCKET
PhysicalLayerPort = 00066604A6E2
PhysicalLayerParams=115200,n,8,1
```

File is much longer but you can get the idea.

Some of the "Name" in the file contain also charters and not only numbers.
int() only sorts numbers.

How can i fix this?

Comment: You have a *hexadecimal number*, not a decimal number..

Comment: @Kasra: that is about **empty** input values, not about hex.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah it should be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python

Comment: So how should names that are not numbers (hexadecimal or otherwise) be treated? How would you sort those if you were doing this by hand?

Comment: Put them at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`5DB7` is not a valid decimal number. Perhaps your numbers are not decimal but *hexadecimal* instead?

If so, tell `int()` to use a different base:

```
int(Config.get(section, 'name'), 16)
```

If you have names in there than don't convert to any number, you'll have to handle those cases explicitly. Catch the conversion:

```
try:
    number = int(Config.get(section, 'name'), 16)
except ValueError:
    # handle a name that doesn't convert, perhaps set a default
    number = float('inf')  # a number that's guaranteed to come last
```

Comment: Could it be that your config file is wrong? The value for _name_ looks like it should be `222` and not `5DB7`.

Comment: @Matthias: there are loads of devices, see Device26 and Device27 for example. From Device31 onwards there are several with non-numeric names.

Comment: @Matthias yes the name is probably wrong but I cant change the name in the file.
Python has to work his way around with this but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Seeing names like `AdBox` this looks like treating this value as a number is just wrong.

Comment: @DjordyWinckler: so why not use the section name to sort on instead? Parse out the number after `Device` for example.

Comment: Because the number after device needs to be changed. it first sorts on Type and then on Name, after sorting on that it changes the Device(number).