# Converting a string of numbers to hex and back to dec pandas python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, hex, decimal, string-conversion

I currently have a string of values which I retrieved after filtering through data from a csv file.  ultimately I had to do some filtering of the data but I have the same numbers as a list, dataframe, or array.  I just need to take the numbers in the string and convert them to hex and then take the first 8 numbers of the hex and convert that to dec for each element in the string.  Lastly I also need to convert the last 8 of the same hex and then to dec as well for each value in the string.

I cannot provide a snippet because it is sensitive data, but here is an example.

I basically have something like this

```
>>> list_A

[52894036, 78893201, 45790373]
```

If I convert it to a dataframe and call `df.dtypes`, it says `dtype: object` and I can convert the values of Column A to bool, int, or string, but the dtype is always an object.

It does not matter whether it is a function, or just a simple loop.  I have been trying many methods and am unable to attain the results I need.  But ultimately the data is taken from different csv files and will never be the same values or list size.

Comment: When you say list, do you mean like this:  ['1234', '0', '5678']

Comment: So to elaborate and simplify the question, I currently decided to create an array of numbers. I am able to convert the values in the array to hex. But the Hex is a combination of two separate decimal numbers. So I have to take the 1st 6 char in hex and convert that to dec (excluding the 'ox' portion) and also take the last 2 char in the hex value and convert that to decimal individually as well. This is what I used to create my hex array. hex_array = [hex(x) for x in dec_array]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pandas is designed to work primarily with integers and floats, with no particular facilities for hexadecimal that I know of, but you can use `apply` to access standard python conversion functions like `hex` and `int`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'a':[52894036999, 78893201999, 45790373999] })
df['b'] = df['a'].apply( hex )
df['c'] = df['b'].apply( int, base=0 )
```

Results:

```
             a             b            c
0  52894036999   0xc50baf407  52894036999
1  78893201999  0x125e66ba4f  78893201999
2  45790373999   0xaa951a86f  45790373999
```

Note that this answer is for Python 3.  For Python 2 you may need to strip off the trailing "L" in column "b" with `str[:-1]`.

Comment: So to elaborate and simplify the question, I currently decided to create an array of numbers. I am able to convert the values in the array to hex.  But the Hex is a combination of two separate decimal numbers.  So I have to take the 1st 6 char in hex and convert that to dec (excluding the 'ox' portion) and also take the last 2 char in the hex value and convert that to decimal individually as well.  This is what I used to create my hex array.  hex_array = [hex(x) for x in dec_array]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found the errors in my code and your snippet works perfectly fine

Comment: Some more options here that can use via `apply`, as above:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python?rq=1