# Read in a dataframe and convert some columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read in a dataframe using read_csv. For example:

```
data = pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep=' ', header=None, dtype={0:np.uint32, 1:np.uint32, 2:np.str})
```

Except foo.txt has the awkward property that the first two columns are in hex.  E.g

```
ff462 44e44 house
```

You can convert a hex value to an int with `int("ff462", 16)`.  How can I read in the data making sure that the first two columns are converted to dtype uint32?

Comment: You can apply a `converters` parameter, which takes a dict, see a good demo on http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/working-with-pandas-dataframes/

Comment: @Jan That looks good. Can you convert hex to uint32 directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in the data as a string and then convert it...

```
data = pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep=' ', header=None, dtype=str)
data.iloc[:, [0, 1]] = df.iloc[:, [0, 1]].apply(lambda x: int(x, base=16)).astype(np.uint32)
```

Comment: Will that make it uint32?

Comment: Updated with a type cast

Comment: Thank you. As the file is very large I would ideally prefer to convert it as it is read but I will try your solution too.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this works ([cf.here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528340/converting-a-string-of-numbers-to-hex-and-back-to-dec-pandas-python)):

```
data['1'] = data.1.apply(lambda x: int(x,base=0) )
data['1'] = data['1'].astype(np.uint32)
```

Comment: Will that make it uint32?