# Display/print column as hex in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this data as a starting point:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = [
  {"colA": "hello", "colB":  22, "colC": 3.0, "colD":   123476},
  {"colA": "there", "colB": 122, "colC": 4.0, "colD":  2384953},
  {"colA": "world", "colB": 222, "colC": 5.0, "colD": 39506483},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', None, 'max_colwidth', 20, 'display.float_format', "{:.2f}".format):
  print(df)
```

It prints:

```
    colA  colB  colC      colD
0  hello    22  3.00    123476
1  there   122  4.00   2384953
2  world   222  5.00  39506483
```

Now, I would like ONLY the integer column B to be printed as hex - more specifically, as "0x{:02X}" string format.

If it existed, I might have used `display.int_format`, but that option does not exist as stated in [Can you format pandas integers for display, like `pd.options.display.float_format` for floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663252/can-you-format-pandas-integers-for-display-like-pd-options-display-float-forma)
... Then again, such an option would likely not allow me to print *ONLY* column B in that way.

Another option is doing `.apply()` as hinted in [Converting a string of numbers to hex and back to dec pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528340/converting-a-string-of-numbers-to-hex-and-back-to-dec-pandas-python):

```python
# ...
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["colB"] = df["colB"].apply("0x{:02X}".format)
# ...
```

... which then prints what I want:

```
    colA  colB  colC      colD
0  hello  0x16  3.00    123476
1  there  0x7A  4.00   2384953
2  world  0xDE  5.00  39506483
```

... however, it *also* changes the data in my table - and I would like to preserve the original data in the table; I simply want to *print* some columns as hex.

So - is there a way to specify only some certain columns to be printed as hex in pandas, while keeping the original data in the table (and without explicitly copying the dataframe to a new one just for that kind of printing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html#pandas-io-formats-style-styler):

```py
style = df.style.format({"colB": "0x{:02X}"}, precision=2)
print(style.to_string(delimiter="\t"))
```

Prints:

```
        colA    colB    colC    colD
0       hello   0x16    3.00    123476
1       there   0x7A    4.00    2384953
2       world   0xDE    5.00    39506483
```

Comment: Awesome, that works - and first time I see that .style can be also used for plain text!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the DataFrame.style.format method, which allows you to specify custom formatting for the display of your DataFrame's data without altering the underlying data itself.

```
formatted_df = df.style.format({
    "colB": "0x{:02X}".format,
})
```