# Python: string to hex literal

Tags: python

I want to convert string that contains hex literal, for example:

```
s = 'FFFF'
```

to hex value that contains literal string, like this:

```
h = 0xFFFF
```

So, I need a function to make this conversion. For example:

```
h = func('FFFF')
```

What function I have to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve? You can't store a *"literal"* in a name, you store the object it represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) has a keyword option `base`:

```
In [1]: s = 'FFFF'

In [2]: int(s, base=16)
Out[2]: 65535
```

Comment: Ok. What I want is FFFF in var, not 65535, how I can perform this?

Comment: @jgd that doesn't make conceptual sense. `65535` **is** `0xFFFF`, they are just two different literal forms of the same object (which is really stored in binary somewhere in your computer's memory), but you will always see the integer `repr` form when you e.g. `print` it. If you want the *string* `'0xFFFF'` you can use `hex`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hex form to be the actual `repr`esentation of your object, you would need to sub-class `int` and implement `__repr__`:

```
class Hex(int):

    def __new__(cls, arg, base=16):
        if isinstance(arg, basestring):
            return int.__new__(cls, arg, base)
        return int.__new__(cls, arg)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '0x{:X}'.format(self)
```

Here I have also implemented `__new__` to make `16` (rather than `10`) the default `base`, so you can do things like:

```
>>> Hex('FFFF')  # base defaults to 16
0xFFFF
>>> Hex('42', 10)  # still supports other bases
0x2A
>>> Hex(65535)  # and numbers
0xFFFF
```

You will also have to [emulate a numeric type](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) to allow `Hex` instances to be used in addition, subtraction, etc. (otherwise you'll just get a plain `int` back).