# generate random long in python OR convert str to long

Tags: python

I need to generate random variable type=long, so it should looks like:x=0xabcdef1234567890

EDIT:

```
>>> x='0xa123456789abcdef'
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> long(x, 16)
11611200575284956655L         
>>> x=0xa123456789abcdef       
>>> type(x)
<type 'long'>
```

Comment: You're looking at a hexadecimal number (represented by prefixing with `0x...`): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: `x=0xabcdef1234567890`  is creating a long  ... what does the string have to do with anything ...

Comment: the question is: How to generate randomly variable with type=long ?

Comment: Since long has unlimited precision, you cannot generate a random value with uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0xabcdef1234567890
type(x) #long
x = 51924361L
type(x) #long
x = 0xDEFABCECBDAECBFBAEl
type(x) #long
x = -4721885298529L
type(x) #long

x = long(1)
type(x) #long


def generate_random_long():
    import random
    return long(random.choice(range(0,10000000)))

def generate_random_long_from_string():
    import random
    return long('0x'+''.join(random.choice('0123456789abcdef') for n in xrange(12)),16)
```

Comment: how to get value (ex: x = 0xabcdef1234567890) randomly?

Comment: Note that `long()` does not exists anymore in python3. Use `int()` instead.