# Binary Data in Python

Tags: python

I have a string of binary I'm trying to convert to ints.  The chunks were originally 8 hex chars each and converted into binary.  How do you turn it into its 64-bit int value?

```
s = 'Q\xcb\x80\x80\x00\x00\x01\x9bQ\xcc\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9b'
date_chunk = s[0:8]
value_chunk = s[8:]
```

Looks like hex now that I got it to print.  How do I make two ints?  The first is a date encoded to seconds since epoch.

Comment: you have the string in unicode?

Comment: Should there be quotes on that variable? Like `s = 'Q...'`?

Comment: That isn't a valid Python statement.  Show some real code with expected and received results, and Python version used.

Comment: You can pull integers out of binary using the `struct` module.

Comment: How was the original data translated to binary? Do you have the code which performs it? It's impossible to know how to convert it back without knowing the encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `struct` module unpacks binary.  Use `qq` for signed ints.

```
>>> s = 'Q\xcb\x80\x80\x00\x00\x01\x9bQ\xcc\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9b'
>>> len(s)
16
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>QQ',s) # big-endian
(5893945824588595611L, 5894316909762970011L)
>>> struct.unpack('<QQ',s) # little-endian
(11169208553011465041L, 11169208550869355601L)
```

You also mentioned an original 8 hex chars.  Use the `binascii.unhexlify` function in that case.  Example:

```
>>> s = '11223344'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify(s)
'\x11"3D'
>>> struct.unpack('>L',binascii.unhexlify(s))
(287454020,)
>>> hex(287454020)
'0x11223344'
```

Comment: you sure it's unsigned?

Comment: @Chad, Nope, just as I am unsure if it is big- or little-endian.

Comment: OP converted hex to binary.... I assume in the same program so I'm betting on native format `"@QQ"`.

Comment: Both numbers seem quite large for *seconds* since an epoch, but if the OP wants to tell us what the expected date should be and what epoch it is based....

Answer (score 0):

```
import struct
struct.unpack(">QQ",s)
```

Or

```
struct.unpack("<QQ",s)
```

Depending on the endianness of the machine that generated the bytes

Comment: Good answer but 5 minutes too late. This answer has already been posted.