# Convert : hexadecimal string to decimal integer with Python

Tags: python, hex, decimal

I am new Python user and I am trying to convert hexadecimal string to decimal integer with Python. 
In my system, I send analogue values like :

```
import serial 
import binascii 

ser = serial.Serial(port = 'COM3',
    baudrate = 9600,
    bytesize=8,
    parity='N',
    stopbits=1,
    timeout =None) # my parameter to communicate with my card
ser.open() 
a = binascii.a2b_hex('010f0001000000c8d9') # transform hexadecimal under binary format (no problem)
u = ser.write(a) # send binary data (no problem, it works fine)
i = ser.read(u) # read the answer 
i 
# I get that hexadecimal string : '\x02\x01d\x0f\x00\x00\x02\xbf7'
```

What I tried :

```
int(i, 0)
```

it did not work,and I did not find anywhere how I can translate that into a decimal. Does someone know?

Comment: What's the output for `i`?

Comment: hex would be base 16 not 0

Comment: Why `i = ser.read(u)` and not `i=ser.read()`?

Comment: I think you need to check what you are receiving is correct from your serial port...

Comment: Also, Check that you are setting up the correct parameters for the Serial protocol .. baudrate, bytesize, parity..etc...This can receiving non-formatted data...

Comment: The output for i is composed with smileys and all. 
I checked the parameters they are correct. :)

Comment: @Dianou seems you are having good Chat with your device ... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the binary representation in i. To keep with the logic of your program you can use binascii.b2a_hex to convert it to a string of hex digits, and then use int(string,16) to convert it to a decimal int.

```
b = binascii.b2a_hex(i)
number = int(b,16)
```

Mind you, it's going to be a long int, so handle it with care

Comment: That does not match what is sent

Comment: As I understand it doesn't need to. They program just sends a value, and the card in the other end responds with a different value of the same size

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Does it have to be the same?...Because it's communicating with another device...not looping, unless OP confirms it to be so...

Comment: In that case there is no need for binascii at all. Int.from_bytes will do