# Decimal color to hexadecimal python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying convert decimal color to hexadecimal.

For example, yellow color is `#FFFF00` and there decimal is `16776960`.

How can I convert to *hexadecimal* ( `#FFFF00` ) from *decimal* ( `16776960` ) ?

I tried to use this:

```
color = 16776960
hex(color)
```

and tried with `hex(int(color))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: FYI, colors are usually hex triplets. Is it really meaningful to have a decimal representation of the whole string? I'd think you'd want `#FFFF00` to map to `(256, 256, 0)`. Though reading closely it looks like you already have the decimal color, for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem, sorry for inconvenice.

```
xxxs = int(xxx)
color = hex(xxxs).replace("0x", "")
print "color to hexa "+str(color)+""
this.c.colornick = "#"+str(color)
```