# Convert a long hex string into hex number in Python

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a long hex string, e.g, '0x0000fffffffffffff000000000ffffff'.

How to convert it to exact the same hex number: 0x0000fffffffffffff000000000ffffff

Comment: Can you include the code you tried and the output it generated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> eval('0x0000fffffffffffff000000000ffffff')
5192296858534826475608991739150335
>>> hex(eval('0x0000fffffffffffff000000000ffffff'))
'0xfffffffffffff000000000ffffff' #unnecessary zeros is omitted here
```

But if you need to get a number with fixed length of 32 digits, here is solution:

```
def hex_op(hex_number):
    len_ = len(hex_number[2:])
    if len_ < 32: #checking if number has less than 32 digits
        return "0x" + "0"*(32-len_) + hex_number[2:]
    else:
        return hex_number
```

And usage example:

```
>>> hex_op('0xfffffffffffff000000000ffffff') # our number that we got from previous example
'0x0000fffffffffffff000000000ffffff'
```