# Python String byte to HEX with IF condition

Tags: python-2.7

I want to convert the byte string to hex for below variable.I want the result as DTCLogged[loopindex] = 0xDA

```
>>> DTCLogged[loopindex]
   'DA'
```

After that it should satisfy the IF condition

```
if (DTCLogged[loopindex] & 0xC0)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `int('da', 16) == 218`, it that's what you're after. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/209513/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse it as a hexadecimal integer:

```
x = int(DTCLogged[loopindex], 16) & 0xC0
```