# Decoding list of hex in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I have a list of hex that I would like to transform into a list of unicode characters. Everything here is done with python-3.5.

If I do `print(binary.fromhex('hex_number').decode('utf-8'))` it works. But does not work if, after the conversion, I store, again, the chars in the list:

```
a = ['0063'] # Which is the hex equivalent to the c char.
b = [binary.fromhex(_).decode('utf-8') for _ in a]
print(b)
```

will print

```
['\x00c']
```

instead of

```
['c']
```

while the code

```
a = ['0063']
for _ in a:
    print(binary.fromhex(_).decode('utf-8'))
```

prints, has expected:

```
c
```

Can someone explain to me how I can convert the list `['0063']` in the list `['c']` and why I get this strange (to me) behavior?

To see what the `0063` hex corresponds look  [here](https://codepoints.net/U+0063).

Comment: Why would `0063`, decoded as UTF-8, *ever* produce `'c'`? And why would `030C` map to a space (which encodes to `20` in UTF-8 hex)?

Comment: I can't figure out what codec you are thinking of here. U+030C maps to the COMBINING CARON codepoint in the Unicode standard, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `0063` in hex corresponds to the 'c' in utf-8 (would be U+0063). This is easy to see if you just use the code above. The `030C` corresponds to the COMBINING CARON, as you said. As I said in the question, this is shown as a space in my shell (probably because my shell is not able to map it to something). Honestly, I do not understand what is wrong with my question. I did not put much attention to the COMBINING CARON just because it was not really important to answer the question. But if you think, I can write something different that can be easily mapped by my shell.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think now should be more clear based on your comments. Otherwise, just let me know.

Comment: Right, you appear to have confused *Unicode codepoints* with UTF-8. U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C  is `63` in UTF-8, while U+030C COMBINING CARON is `CC8C`. Unicode codepoints != UTF-8. Perhaps you are thinking of UTF-16 (big endian order) instead?

Comment: Note that the link you included in your question *includes encoding examples*. Look closely at the UTF-8 and UTF-16 examples in the *Representations* section.

Comment: It's a pity you don't have more data to show us. The CC8C might have been another clue, but *more data* from your actual usecase would have been helpful in identifying what codec you really have. It is not UTF-8, at any rate.

Comment: The basic idea is that I want to remap some non-ascii char to ascii (there is a software I cannot access the code that works only with ascii so I need some basic mapping). I was just playing with the "decomposition mapping" field of the codepoints.net website. The chars there are stored as unicode-codepoint that I was trying to convert to "normal" string.

Comment: That'd be a whole new can of worms. See [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors](//stackoverflow.com/q/2365411)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have UTF-8 data, if 0063 is [U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C](https://codepoints.net/U+0063). **At best** you have [UTF-16 data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), big endian order:

```
>>> binary.fromhex('0063').decode('utf-16-be')
'c'
```

You may want to check if your *full* data starts with a [*Byte Order Mark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), for big-endian UTF-16 that'd be `'FEFF'` in hex, at which point you can drop the `-be` suffix as the decoder will know what byte order to use. If your data starts with `'FFFE'` instead, you have *little-endian* encoded UTF-16 and you sliced your data at the wrong point; in that case you took along the `'00'` byte for the preceding codepoint.

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a *variable width* encoding. The first 128 codepoints in the Unicode standard (corresponding with the ASCII range), encode directly to single bytes, mapping directly to the ASCII standard. Codepoints in the Latin-1 range and beyond (up to U+07FF<sup>(*)</sup>, the next 1919 codepoints) map to two bytes, etc.

If your input really was UTF-8, then you really have a [`\x00` NULL character](https://codepoints.net/U+0000) before that `'c'`. Printing a NULL results in no output on many terminals, but you can use `cat -v` to turn such non-printable characters into *caret escape codes*:

```
$ python3 -c "print('\x00c')"
c
$ python3 -c "print('\x00c')" | cat -v
^@c
```

`^@` is the representation for a NULL in the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) used by `cat`.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> U+07FF is not currently mapped in Unicode; the last UTF-8 two-byte codepoint currently possible is [U+07FA NKO LAJANYALAN](https://codepoints.net/U+07FA).

Comment: Ok... Maybe I am starting to understand this stuff. Unicode is a set of conventions on how to store the chars in the memory. utf-8 is following those conventions using only 8-bit. When I encode something which require more than 8-bit, that will be encoded using 16-bit and so on (this is done in an automagically way: the official encode is still utf-8). This works in encoding. When I want to decode something, I must know "a-priori" how many bits I am going to use. This means that if I have a non-ascii char I cannot use utf-8 for sure. Is this right?

Comment: UTF-8 is one of a set of possible *serialisations* of the Unicode text. Unicode is much more than just a bunch of codepoints; those conventions go beyond mere serialisation. UTF-8 can represent everything in Unicode, using a variable number of bytes. UTF-16 and UTF-32 are other serialisations, and they use a fixed number of bytes (2 and 4) per codepoint (where UTF-16 would use 2x 2 bytes for Unicode codepoints outside of the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), called surrogate pairs).

Comment: 8-bit is not a characterisation to apply here. You need to know, a-priory, what serialisation standard (codec) was used. You can do *some* finger-printing, if your data starts with `0000FEFF` or `FFFE0000` then can assume, with high probability, that you have data using UTF-32 as the codec, for example.

Comment: Sorry to bore you, but I am learning a lot from this discussion. The idea is that if you go from str->bytes you can use utf-8 because that is using a variable number of bytes. While when you go bytes->str you must know the codec used to create those bytes otherwise you cannot interpret the bytes. This break something I was believing: utf-8 is just the most space-saving among all the utf-* but they are interchangeable.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia: Most codecs are not interchangeable. When you encode from `str` to `bytes`, you made a *conscious choice* to use the UTF-8 codec. You could have picked a different codec too. If you always settle for UTF-8, then you can always use the same codec too. If you don't, you need to record your selected codec somewhere. In XML documents, the first [XML declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology) is such a place. In HTML, a [`<meta>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type) is often used.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia: in other words, if you are dealing with data from arbitrary sources, look for standard indicators for the codec, including the documented standard for the format.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia: I recommend you read up on Unicode and codecs: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ are good starting points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient. I already read something but apparently was not really enough.... :) I will take the time to read what you pointed me out. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['0063'] # Which is the hex equivalent to the c char.
b = [chr(int(x,16)) for x in a]
print(b)
```

Thanks to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209550/886607)

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters Just to understand better: is this solution agnostic of the codec used? (Maybe I should do a new question).

Comment: It works as your question needs and work for any Unicode character. You may need to use another input instead of using array of string of hex numbers as input.