# Append 2 hex values in python not working

Tags: python

Let's say I have two given hex values which are str as datatype:

```
a = 0x15
b = 0x18
```

Now I would like to append  them so that I have as result:

```
0x1518
```

The normal way would be to cast the values to int to be able to append, like:

```
(hex( (int(a)<<8) | int(b) ))
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x15'
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `a` is already an `int`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: I get no error. Works in Thonny with python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `int` that the numbers are in base 16:

```
hex((int(a, 16) << 8) | int(b, 16))
```

Answer (score 1):

a and b are int values already you don't have to cast them

```
hex_value = hex(a << 8 | b)
```

if it still doesn't work you can use the string format to convert the int into hex

```
hex_value = '0x{:04x}'.format(a << 8 | b)
```

Answer (score 0):

*The code you're running is not the code you posted.*  (what you posted, works fine).

Your 'a' is not what you think it is. You're trying to feed the string "0x15" to the int() function, and it rightfully complains to you that this isn't an integer in base 10 notation.

Fix your variable types and get rid of the int() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works fine. I don't know where you are getting the error from.

On a side note, `a` and `b` are not strings; they are already of type `int` so there is no need to type-cast. You can verify this:

```
>>> a = 0x15
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

Removing unnecessary type-casting you get `(hex(a << 8 | b ))`, which will give you the correct result.

Comment: when I type  type(a) I get "str". This value is received from an other module in str datatype. For further use I needed to convert it to string.