# Python stenography too many values to unpack error

Tags: python, error-handling, png

I am getting the error `too many values to unpack (expected 3)`.
When i add `[]` in case it is a tuple itself it i get the error `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`
The error rises on line 50, `r, g, b = hex2rgb(newpix)`

I am going to share the entire code as i am not sure if this is the only error i am getting.

My goal is to insert a string into a .png file.
I used to use python around 10 years back, i am a C# user so excuse me if this is too nooby as a question

Thank you
P.S. i am not very good at expressing myself, feel free to edit the post

```
from PIL import Image
import binascii
import optparse

def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g, b)

def hex2rgb(hexcode):
    return tuple(map(ord, hexcode[1:]))

def str2bin(message):
    binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message.encode()), 16))
    return binary[2:]

def bin2str(binary):
    message = binascii.unhexlify('%x' % (int('0b' + binary, 2)))
    return message

def encode(hexcode, digit):
    if hexcode[-1] in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
        hexcode = hexcode[:-1] + digit
        return hexcode
    else:
        return None


def decode(hexcode):
    if hexcode[-1] in ('0', '1'):
        return hexcode[-1]
    else:
        return None


def hide(filename, message):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    binary = str2bin(message) + '1111111111111110'
    if img.mode in ('RGBA'):
        img = img.convert('RGBA')
        datas = img.getdata()

        newData = []
        digit = 0
        temp = ''
        for item in datas:
            if (digit < len(binary)):
                newpix = encode(rgb2hex(item[0], item[1], item[2]), binary[digit])
                if newpix == None:
                    newData.append(item)
                else:
                    r, g, b = [hex2rgb(newpix)]
                    newData.append((r, g, b, 255))
                    digit =+ 1
            else:
                newData.append(item)
        img.putdata(newData)
        img.save(filename, "PNG")
        return "Completed!"
    return "Incorrect Image mode, couldn't hide"

def retr(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    binary = ''

    if img.mode in ('RGBA'):
        img = img.convert('RGBA')
        datas = img.getdata()

        for item in datas:
            digit = decode(rgb2hex(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
            if digit == None:
                pass
            else:
                binary = binary + digit
                if (binary[-16:] == '1111111111111110'):
                    print("Success")
                    return bin2str(binary[:-16])
        return bin2str(binary)
    return "Incorrect Image mode, couldn't retrieve"

def Main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog ' + '-e/-d <target file>')
    parser.add_option('-e', dest = 'hide', type = 'string', help = 'target picture path to hide text')
    parser.add_option('-d', dest = 'retr', type = 'string', help = 'target picture to retrieve text')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if (options.hide != None):
        text = input("Enter a message to hide: ")
        print(hide(options.hide, text))
    elif(options.retr != None):
        print(retr(optrions.retr))
    else:
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on where in your code this error is raised? It would help if you supply us with the exact error message that you get.

Comment: I added on the post. It rises on the call of hex2rgb function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> hex2rgb('#abcdef')
(97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102)
```

Here I use your `hex2rgb()` function without assigning the output to any variables. It returns 6 values, as you would expect since you decode every char from the hexadecimal value (`a` for instance) into an integer unicode code point that corresponds to hexadecimal `a`: `97`. ([see documentation or ord() here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#ord))

```
>>> r,g,b = hex2rgb('#abcdef')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

When trying to unpack them into three variables, it raises an error because your function returns 6 variables instead of the expected 3.

```
>>> r,g,b = [hex2rgb('#abcdef')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Your approach to wrap the 6 integers into a list reduces the return value from being 6 variables into being only 1 value (the list with 6 items), and thus this does not solve your problem.

To solve your problem you should find a way to end up with 3 integers instead of 6. For this, you need a different approach for decoding your HEX value.

The RGB pairs in my example are made up of Red=AB, Green=CD, Blue=EF. By using `map()` with `ord()` you translate `A` and `B` separately to an integer, which is not what you want, as you end up with 2 integers (`97` and `98`) instead of 1 integer (`171`) corresponding to the `AB` value.

So what you want is:

```
>>> int("0xAB",0)
171
```

As you can see, converting `AB` together would return the right value (171). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209550/4994839) for an example of how to do that. Modify your `hex2rgb()` to do this.

Last but not least, your approach to use `ord()` to decode the chars into integers is interesting, but might not be correct, as `A` and `a` have a different unicode code point value (`A = 65`, `a = 97`), and thus they result in different values for your color. In HEX-color codes there is no difference between uppercase or lowercase letters. When you use the method with `int()` as described above, the result will be the same for characters in lower- or uppercase, and thus be more correct.