# Create a program to convert hexadecimal in decimal (python)

Tags: python

I have to create a program in Python that will convert a hexadecimal number to a decimal number, for example from `FA2` to `4002`.

I have to write the function `hexa2dec(c)` where `c` is a string input parameter and the returned value is of type `int`.
I've started by creating a dictionary :

```
dic={"0":0, "1":1, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "A":10, "B":11, "C":12, "D":13, "E":14, "F":15}
```

and my code is  this:

```
c = "F"

def hexa2dec(c):

   d = ""   

   if c[0]=="F":

      d = dic["F"]*(16**(len(c)-1))

  return d
```

But I know that it's very bad, for example I don't know what will the length that a person can enter if this person for example does `print(hexa2dec(F4CF))`.
I know that with `len(i)` I can know the length but does it help ?

Comment: Why not just `int(c, 16)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: thank you for your awnser but my professor wants that we do it with a function

Comment: it's not a duplicate

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python convert hex to decimal" or "Python convert base", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @BoarGules, it doesn't say that anywhere in the question. Most people want the best and easiest fix.

Comment: @BoarGules I assume the answers drew the conclusion from *"thank you for your awnser but my professor wants that we do it with a function"*, which was written after I made my comment.

Comment: @BoarGules Can you please double check your math? The comment was 25 mins ago, the answers 20 mins ago.

Comment: no i just want help, sorry if you think that i want people do everything for me

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a task set to you by your professor, I'm not going to solve it for you, I'll just give you a few hints:

You can iterate over a string backwards using slice/stride notation: `for digit in hex_string[::-1]:` will do that.

Now you can use a counter variable, use it to calculate the correct power of 16, and increment it in each loop. If you already know the `enumerate()` function, that task becomes even easier.

Use a result variable and add the result of each iteration to it.

That should get you started.

Comment: thanks you, i'm not asking for people do all the work for me. I asked for clues :)

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to just use one of the preprogrammed functions but since you want to code it yourself, I suggest you try using loops. For example a while loop to perform some math on every digit.