# Convert 0x000F to "0F" in python basically trying to convert to ASCII string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to convert hexadecimal value `0x000F` into string value `"0F"` in python? Basically, I've been trying to convert number to string.

Comment: This question might be similar to the following questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python

Comment: Is your input a string like `"0x000F"`, or is it an integer with that value?

Comment: its not a string its a hex value 0x000F and I want to convert it in to string "0F" I do not want to convert to int or anything else .

Comment: There really is no such thing as a "hex value". There are just ints, with hex being one possible form that an int literal can take. You can use `hex(i)` and tweak the resulting string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%` formatting:

```
str = "%02x" % 0x000F
```

`%x` formatting means to format as a float, the `02` prefix means to put it in a 2-digit field with zero padding.