# Discord.py: Set the color of a role from a string, give a error

Tags: discord.py

```
await role.edit(color="#000000")
```

I'm trying to change the color of a role but I get that error: `Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit) you can see that you need to provide a [color](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Colour) to edit the role, not a string. You can do this a number of ways:

```py
# 0x prefix
await role.edit(color=0x000000)

# Color decimal
await role.edit(color=0)

# Using the built in discord.Colour
await role.edit(color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: How can I convert the string to a value that can be used by color? Cause I take in input from a file the color and then I apply it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python this might be what you're looking for :)