# concatenate a string with \x in python 3

Tags: python

Say I have `someString = "00"`. basically I want to convert `someString` to `\x00`
I tried multiple ways to achieve my goal, but couldn't find a successful one.

tried:

```
HexString = '\x'+someString
```

This method throws this error:

> ValueError: invalid \x escape

Unless I do `HexString = r'\x'+someString`, but then `HexString` value is set to `\\x00` which is not the same as I want.

I also tried using `hex()` function, which had few issues. But the big issue I had with it was that it returns `0x0`. It expects `int` and etc...

Can anyone help me with converting a string(`"11"`) to `\x11`?

Comment: By `\x00` do you mean a string that is `"\\x00"` or an integer?

Comment: Does this anwer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python

Comment: @tdelaney to hex, more precisely e.g `\x41` which is equal o `A`

Comment: @JoeFerndz Unfotunetaly no, I want to convert a string to hex, not hex to int. E.g: `\x41` to string `A` in ascii table.

Comment: So, in python terms, that would be "11'' to "A"? I'm still trying to figure out what `\x11` or `\x41` is. You can have an integer, a character in a string or a byte in a bytes array.

Comment: Maybe this? `bytes.fromhex(someString).decode('ascii')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, the **actual goal** is to take a *string* that contains a bunch of pairs of hex digits, and translate each pair of hex digits into the corresponding *byte* and have a result of type `bytes`.

In 3.x, this is built directly into the `bytes` type itself:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('11abcdef')
b'\x11\xab\xcd\xef'
```

You can also instead use the standard library:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('11abcdef')
b'\x11\xab\xcd\xef'
```

You will not necessarily see a `\x` escape sequence for every byte value. This is normal and expected; it has to do with how the `bytes` object is *represented* as text for display purposes.

> `'\x'+someString`

No approach of this general form can work, because it fundamentally misunderstands the problem. The output that you want is **not a string**, and a string literal like `'\x00'` does **not have** a backslash in it, nor a lowercase x - again, what you are seeing is how the string is *represented* as text, because not every character is printable.

Answer (score 3):

`int` lets you set the base. For base 16

```
>>> someString = "00"
>>> int(someString, 16)
0
```

Of course, 0 is kinda boring because it works for all bases.

If you wanted a byte in a bytes object, you could

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("b", int(someString, 16))
b'\x00'
```

If you want a string (and I'm switching to 0x41 here) you could

```
>>> chr(int("41", 16))
'A'
```

Comment: Your method works if the hex value is smaller than 127, meaning if you have `someString = "aa"`, I get this error: `struct.error: byte format requires -128 <= number <= 127`

Comment: @Abdul, glad that last one worked. `struct.pack` lets you build arbitrarily long byte streams based on a format specification. "b" is -127 to 127. "B" is 0-255. "<III" would be 3 unsigned integers of 4 bytes apiece, little-endian.

Answer (score 1):

You can get ord of the character by using `int`, then convert it to a character. Then you can encode it to bytes object without any `import`.

```py
>>> chr(int("11", 16))  # a character
'\x11'
>>> chr(int("11", 16)).encode()  # bytes object
b'\x11'
```