# Storing and retrieving a single byte i2c address with strings

Tags: python

I am trying to store an i2c address, 0x3c, to a string to be stored in a text file that is later read. When reading the text file however, I cannot read the data from the string in the correct way, such that

```
value = string_read(text_file)
print(value == 0x3c)
```

would return true. How can I read a single byte stored in a string:

```
'0x3c'
```

into `value` so that the above code would return true?

Answer (score 3):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/209550/9606335. Specifically, in your example, if you know your string is **only** `"0x3c"`, then you can convert it to a numerical value by `value = int("0x3c", 0)`. Now your expression should behave as you expect:

```
>>> print(int("0x3c", 0) == 0x3c)
True
```