# ValueError: could not convert string to float on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am a beginner and need help with converting str to float on python.

the code seems to work fine locally, but when I deploy on heroku I get

```
"ValueError: could not convert string to float".
```

Is anybody else experiencing this? It would be great if you could help me.

```
2022-01-26T14:40:03.536858+00:00 app[web.1]:
tx_count = float(raw_data["result"].replace("0x", ""))
2022-01-26T14:40:03.536858+00:00 app[web.1]:

#ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Invalid API Key'
```

my code:

```
my_address = request.form["public_key"]
response = requests.get(f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionCount&address={my_address}&tag=latest&apikey={API_KEY}")
raw_data = response.json()
```

raw_data:

```
raw_data = {
 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 
 'id': 1, 
 'result': '0x3'
}
```

I want `raw_data["result"]` to be a number because I want to use the number to calculate.

I created a repository on github
https://github.com/yataishiba/co2-calc-eth

UPDATE
I tried this but it is still not working...
[Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: we have no idea what `raw_data['result']` is. All we know is that it can't be converted to a float. Please read [mcve]

Comment: okay so raw_data = {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'result': '0x3'}
and I am using .replace to remove "0x" so that I can get 3. 
But since 3 is a string, I wanna convert it to a number so that I can use it to calculate. I just edited but question so that you can see my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't throw hex directly at `float()` because the string can contain non-numerical strings; i.e. A-F.

Instead you should use `float.fromhex()`. This will also let you not use `.replace()`. For example:

```
tx_count = float.fromhex(raw_data["result"])
```

Comment: If I try that I get ValueError: invalid hexadecimal floating-point string

Comment: @zceimiz I would double check what data you're passing to it, then. Because `float.fromhex('0x3')` is definitely valid.

Comment: its working fine locally... but when I deploy it on heroku it gives me ```2022-01-26T19:06:19.611150+00:00 app[web.1]:     tx_count = float.fromhex(tx)
2022-01-26T19:06:19.611151+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: invalid hexadecimal floating-point string```

Comment: okay so it termed out that raw_data["result"] was not invalid so the above code did not work. thank you so much for the help