# How to convert string to int type (python)

Tags: python

by reference to this post:
[ValueError: could not convert string to float on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70865315/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-on-heroku)

Others suggesting when converting string to int you have to convert it to float first and then use int()

However, it doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

Here is the code and the error message

```
a = '6,011'
print(int(float(a)))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6,011'

a = '6,011'
print(int(a))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6,011'
```

Comment: Commas should not be there, you need to remove them using the `replace()` function

Comment: this may depend on your LOCALE and need to use a period `.`

Comment: The intent of the question was not clear. Converting to `float` first is if the number has a decimal point. Some cultures use `.` as a decimal point and `,` as a thousands separator; others work the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replace()` function to convert commas to dots, that's why `float()` function fails when converting from string to a float number:

```
a = '6,011'
a = a.replace(",", ".")
print(int(float(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the commas. Try this:

```
a = '6,011'
print(int(a.replace(',', '')))
```

Output:

```
6011
```

But if you are treating `comma(,)` as a decimal and want to get `6` then use this:

```
a = '6,011'
print(int(float(a.replace(',', '.'))))
```

Output:

```
6
```