# I want to convert string 1F to hex 1F in Python, what should I do?

Tags: python

```
num="1F"
nm="1"
nm1="2"
hex(num)^hex(nm)^hex(nm1)
```

I wrote it like the code above, but hex doesn't work properly.

I want to convert the string to hexadecimal, and I want an xor operation of the converted value.

What should I do?

Comment: "hex" does the opposite. Use "int(num, 16)".

Comment: You want to interpret the string as hexadecimal number. It’s already hexadecimal, you don’t need to convert it to hexadecimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex string to integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `num` can be converted to int using `int(num, 16)`. Other variables `nm`, `nm1` are just integers in form of strings. to convert them use `int(nm)`, `int(nm1)`

```
num = "1F"
nm = "1"
nm1 = "2"

result = int(num, 16) ^ int(nm) ^ int(nm1)
print(result)

> 28
```